# How to sort column with English, Japanese entries and null values using custom sorting algorithm in MUI Data Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, codesandbox

I have an MUI data grid. I want to create a custom sorting algorithm for columns which can override the default options offered by MUI. My data fields have data in English, Japanese as well as empty/null values. My expected output is to display columns with following sort order for ascending -

1. A-Z English
2. Remaining Null and Japanese entries in any order

Descending

1. Z-A
2. Remaining Null and Japanese entries in any order

My code is as follows

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";

const handleCellClick = (param, event) => {
  console.log(param);
  console.log(event);
  if (param.colIndex === 2) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
};

const handleRowClick = (param, event) => {
  console.log("Row:");
  console.log(param);
  console.log(event);
};

const columns = [
  {
    field: "id",
    headerName: "ID",
    width: 70
  },
  {
    field: "firstName",
    headerName: "First Name",
    width: 130,
    renderCell: (cellValues) => {
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            color: "blue",
            fontSize: 18,
            width: "100%",
            textAlign: "right"
          }}
        >
          {cellValues.value}
        </div>
      );
    }
  },
  { field: "lastName", headerName: "Last Name", width: 130 },
  {
    field: "age",
    headerName: "Age",
    type: "number",
    //width: 90,
    minWidth: 90,
    flex: 1
    //align: "left"
  },
  {
    field: "fullName",
    headerName: "Full name",
    description: "This column has a value getter and is not sortable.",
    sortable: false,
    minWidth: 160,
    flex: 2,
    //width: 160,
    valueGetter: (params) => {
      return `${params.getValue(params.id, "firstName") || ""} ${
        params.getValue(params.id, "lastName") || ""
      }`;
    }
  }
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: "Snow", firstName: "Jon", age: 35 },
  { id: 2, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Amy", age: 42 },
  {
    id: 3,
    lastName: "IGOTAREALL",
    firstName: "Jaime",
    age: 45
  },
  { id: 4, lastName: "Stark", firstName: "Arya", age: 16 },
  { id: 5, lastName: "Targaryen", firstName: "Daenerys", age: 12 },
  { id: 6, lastName: "Melisandre", firstName: "Jane", age: 15 },
  { id: 7, lastName: "榎原", firstName: "しよう", age: 44 },
  { id: 8, lastName: "田中", firstName: "田畑", age: 36 },
  { id: 9, lastName: "瀬奈", firstName: "健治", age: 65 }
];

export default function DataGridDemo() {
  

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 500, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        rowHeight={50}
        className={"hello"}
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={10}
        checkboxSelection
        onCellClick={handleCellClick}
        onRowClick={handleRowClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it would be something like the following ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-uljjvj?file=/demo.js)). You can customize the `isEnglish()` and `isNull()` utility functions to suit your needs, and in the case of the `Full name` column you could build the full `${firstName} ${lastName}` string for comparison if you wanted to.

```
const columns = [
  {
    field: "lastName",
    headerName: "Last Name",
    width: 130,
    sortComparator: (v1, v2) => {
      const isEnglish = (s) => /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test(s);
      const isNull = (s) => (s == undefined || s.trim() === '');

      return (isNull(v1) || !isEnglish(v1)) - (isNull(v2) || !isEnglish(v2)) || v1.localeCompare(v2)
    }
  },
  {
    field: "fullName",
    headerName: "Full name",
    minWidth: 160,
    flex: 2,
    //width: 160,
    valueGetter: (params) => {
      return `${params.getValue(params.id, "firstName") || ""} ${params.getValue(params.id, "lastName") || ""
        }`;
    },
    sortComparator: (v1, v2, param1, param2) => {
      const isEnglish = (s) => /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test(s);
      const isNull = (s) => s == undefined || s.trim() === '';

      const a = param1.api.getCellValue(param1.id, 'firstName');
      const b = param2.api.getCellValue(param2.id, 'firstName');

      return (isNull(a) || !isEnglish(a)) - (isNull(b) || !isEnglish(b)) || a.localeCompare(b)
    }
  }
]
```

#### Edit

The data-grid assumes a symmetric sort and so just reverses the logic for 'desc'. To account for this you need to intervene by detecting the sort direction and manually reversing the initial value in the OR statement to continue to sort to the bottom. You can access the current state through either of the `param` arguments passed to the comparator:

```
const isDesc = param1.api.state.sorting.sortModel[0].sort === "desc";
```

You can then use this boolean to adjust the first OR value:

```
((isNull(v1) || !isEnglish(v1)) - (isNull(v2) || !isEnglish(v2))) * (isDesc ? -1 : 1) 
|| v1.localeCompare(v2)
```

The complete solution then might be something like the following:

```
  {
    field: "lastName",
    headerName: "Last Name",
    width: 130,
    sortComparator: (v1, v2, param1) => {
      const isEnglish = (s) => /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test(s);
      const isNull = (s) => s == undefined || s.trim() === "";
      const shouldSortToEnd = (s) => isNull(s) || !isEnglish(s);

      const isDesc = param1.api.state.sorting.sortModel[0].sort === "desc";

      return (
        (shouldSortToEnd(v1) - shouldSortToEnd(v2)) * (isDesc ? -1 : 1) ||
        v1.localeCompare(v2)
      );
    }
  },
```

---

This is based on a `sort()` using OR short-circuit:

```js
const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: "Snow", firstName: "Jon", age: 35 },
  { id: 2, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Amy", age: 42 },
  { id: 3, lastName: "IGOTAREALL", firstName: "Jaime", age: 45 },
  { id: 4, lastName: "Stark", firstName: "Arya", age: 16 },
  { id: 5, lastName: "Targaryen", firstName: "Daenerys", age: 12 },
  { id: 6, lastName: null, firstName: "Jane", age: 15 },
  { id: 7, lastName: "榎原", firstName: "しよう", age: 44 },
  { id: 8, lastName: "田中", firstName: "田畑", age: 36 },
  { id: 9, lastName: "瀬奈", firstName: "健治", age: 65 }
];

rows.sort((a, b) => {
  const isEnglish = (s) => /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test(s);
  const isNull = (s) => s == undefined || s === '';

  a = a.lastName;
  b = b.lastName;

  return (isNull(a) || !isEnglish(a)) - (isNull(b) || !isEnglish(b)) || a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(rows.map(({ lastName }) => lastName).join(', '));
```

see:

- [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)
- [Javascript find if english alphabets only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402886/javascript-find-if-english-alphabets-only)

Comment: Thank you. Will try this out. While switching to descending, I want the order to be Z-A followed by the null or japanese. In this case, it seems to be sending the Japanese and null on top and then followed by Z-A. How do I add that?

Comment: Yes, you’ll need to detect sort direction and account for it, I can make a sample.

Comment: Yes please that would be helpful

Comment: Edited with descending adjustments

Comment: I want to apply this logic. However I dont directly have the values in the column. I am using enderCell to map the id of each value to the actual string to be displayed in the field. And that final string is what I want to sort. This would sort the IDs instead which are numbers. How do I sort the values that I get after mapping?