# Remove all special characters except space from a string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, special-characters

I want to remove all special characters except space from a string using JavaScript.

For example,
`abc's test#s`
should output as
`abcs tests`.

Comment: How do you define special character?

Comment: With regular expression

var = string.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''); 

Live Example : https://helpseotools.com/text-tools/remove-special-characters

Answer (score 563, accepted):

You should use the string replace function, with a single regex.
Assuming by special characters, you mean anything that's not letter, here is a solution:

```js
const str = "abc's test#s";
console.log(str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, ""));
```

Comment: To use this solution on non-latin alphabet please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/150078/3765109) out

Comment: This will also removed numerical characters!

Comment: Actually you need this `str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");` notice there's a space between 0-9 and ]

Comment: It need some tweak, it didn't remove / or - characters and the first character of camelCase supposed to be in lower case, but this one in uppercase.

Comment: This leaves stuff like: `pspanspanstrongItem SKUstrongnbspspanspanKBRspanspanpp` [This](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/) is a bit better.

Comment: This does not work for Arabic, Chinese, German, French etc special symbols

Comment: this does not remove carriage return `\n`

Answer (score 210):

You can do it specifying the characters you want to remove:

```
string = string.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
```

Alternatively, to change all characters except numbers and letters, try:

```
string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
```

Comment: what if I don't wanna remove space using this? `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g`

Comment: @ArbazAbid to keep space just  add that to white listed characters. your regex would be "/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g" (notice whitespace after 9)

Comment: This was the answer that worked, if a space is required.

Comment: this replaces `()` and `whitespaces` in string `.text().replace(/[ ()]/g, '')`

Comment: What does that regex represent? anything but alphanumeric chars? What is the negation symbol in regex?

Comment: @Jwan622 It represents everything that is not (^) letters (a-zA-Z), numbers (0-9) and a space ( ). So the negation would be something like "replace everything that is not letters, numbers and space by...".

Answer (score 35):

The first solution does not work for any UTF-8 alphabet. (It will cut text such as Привіт). I have managed to create a function which does not use RegExp and use good UTF-8 support in the JavaScript engine. The idea is simple if a symbol is equal in uppercase and lowercase it is a special character. The only exception is made for whitespace.

```
function removeSpecials(str) {
    var lower = str.toLowerCase();
    var upper = str.toUpperCase();

    var res = "";
    for(var i=0; i<lower.length; ++i) {
        if(lower[i] != upper[i] || lower[i].trim() === '')
            res += str[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

**Update:** Please note, that this solution works only for languages where there are small and capital letters. In languages like Chinese, this won't work.

**Update 2:** I came to the original solution when I was working on a fuzzy search. If you also trying to remove special characters to implement search functionality, there is a better approach. Use any [transliteration library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unidecode) which will produce you string only from Latin characters and then the simple Regexp will do all magic of removing special characters. (This will work for Chinese also and you also will receive side benefits by making `Tromsø` == `Tromso`).

Comment: Thank you for this quite creative solution. It is much more in line with how languages actually work, since many of us don't consider "Привіт" or "æøå" special characters. Most solutions out there cut any character that isn't part of the English alphabet.

Comment: Almost the perfect answer for me, but unfortunately it considers Chinese characters to be special characters.

Comment: @EricMajerus and hindi too

Comment: Be careful, this also considers numbers as special characters.

Answer (score 16):

search all not (word characters || space):

```
str.replace(/[^\w ]/, '')
```

Comment: perfect! removing all special unicode characters from the string.

Comment: This was a nice solution I used for searching through first+last name.  It handles accented characters (é) as well.  I added a apostrophe to handle names like D'Angelo.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know JavaScript, but isn't it possible using regex?

Something like `[^\w\d\s]` will match anything but digits, characters and whitespaces. It would be just a question to find the syntax in JavaScript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4374890/2384606

This is the answer to your question :)

Answer (score 11):

```js
const str = "abc's@thy#^g&test#s";
console.log(str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, ""));
```

Comment: pls, add explaination of what u did

Comment: Numbers are not special characters and they will be deleted

Comment: Letters like `ąčęėįšųūž` may not be "special" characters in some context and they will be removed. Also all japanese/chinese  and other languages with local letters. This code will keep only english alphabet a-z and A-Z.

Answer (score 10):

I tried Seagul's very creative solution, but found it treated numbers also as special characters, which did not suit my needs. So here is my (failsafe) tweak of Seagul's solution...

```
//return true if char is a number
function isNumber (text) {
  if(text) {
    var reg = new RegExp('[0-9]+$');
    return reg.test(text);
  }
  return false;
}

function removeSpecial (text) {
  if(text) {
    var lower = text.toLowerCase();
    var upper = text.toUpperCase();
    var result = "";
    for(var i=0; i<lower.length; ++i) {
      if(isNumber(text[i]) || (lower[i] != upper[i]) || (lower[i].trim() === '')) {
        result += text[i];
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
  return '';
}
```

Comment: You forgot to declare `reg` in your first function.

Answer (score 8):

Try to use this one

```
var result= stringToReplace.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '')
```

`[^]` is for negation, `\w` for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` word characters and `\s` for space,
`/[]/g` for global

Answer (score 7):

With regular expression

```
let string  = "!#This tool removes $special *characters* /other/ than! digits, characters and spaces!!!$";

var NewString= string.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
console.log(NewString);
```

Result //This tool removes special characters other than digits characters and spaces

**Live Example :** https://helpseotools.com/text-tools/remove-special-characters

Answer (score 0):

dot (.) may not be considered special. I have added an OR condition to Mozfet's & Seagull's answer:

```
function isNumber (text) {
      reg = new RegExp('[0-9]+$');
      if(text) {
        return reg.test(text);
      }
      return false;
    }

function removeSpecial (text) {
  if(text) {
    var lower = text.toLowerCase();
    var upper = text.toUpperCase();
    var result = "";
    for(var i=0; i<lower.length; ++i) {
      if(isNumber(text[i]) || (lower[i] != upper[i]) || (lower[i].trim() === '') || (lower[i].trim() === '.')) {
        result += text[i];
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
  return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const strippedString = htmlString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
console.log(strippedString);
```

Comment: This would leave the ' and # in the stripped string.  Example output: "abc's test#s"

Answer (score -1):

```js
const input = `#if_1 $(PR_CONTRACT_END_DATE) == '23-09-2019' # 
Test27919<alerts@imimobile.com> #elseif_1 $(PR_CONTRACT_START_DATE) ==  '20-09-2019' #
Sender539<rama.sns@gmail.com> #elseif_1 $(PR_ACCOUNT_ID) == '1234' #
AdestraSID<hello@imimobile.co> #else_1#Test27919<alerts@imimobile.com>#endif_1#`;
const replaceString = input.split('$(').join('->').split(')').join('<-');


console.log(replaceString.match(/(?<=->).*?(?=<-)/g));
```

Answer (score -17):

Whose special characters you want to remove from a string, prepare a list of them and then user javascript replace function to remove all special characters.

```
var str = 'abc'de#;:sfjkewr47239847duifyh';
alert(str.replace("'","").replace("#","").replace(";","").replace(":",""));
```

or you can run loop for a whole string and compare single single character with the ASCII code and regenerate a new string.

Comment: No, please don't do that.  It's really terribly slow.  It is much, much better to use a regular expression.

Comment: This solution is very nice for replacing just one character. In my case it was helpful, thanks.

Comment: Instead of using replace method many times, please use it once only using regular expressions.

Comment: If more characters come up this solution fails, regular exp is generic way of doing this and is fast