# Special character check bypassed by regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string `str= "C - IND - Mom&amp;s >s Restaurantzxc"`. I want to remove the special characters `&amp;` from it using regex but the test is failing & I am getting the same string after replacing the special characters.

This is what I have done :

```
str=str.replace('/\&amp;/g', '&');
```

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all special characters except space from a string using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555182/remove-all-special-characters-except-space-from-a-string-using-javascript)

Comment: What is your expected output? Note you have `''` around the regex, remove them: `str=str.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');`. See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2sgq2b3n/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

`str=str.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');` without the quotes around /&/ ie regex match otherwise it will be treated as string match

Comment: Good. Leave in the `g` modifier.

Comment: @trincot thanks forgot that one. also i dont think string match will do global match so removed that code