# Field validation for a jsp-form

Tags: java, javascript, oracle, validation, jsp

I have a jsp-form with field named `Description`. This field declared as follows

```
<input type="text" name="description">
```

This value used to compose SQL query:

> select * from Engines where description like '% (Value from the field)%'

When a user enters alphanumeric characters it works fine, but it fails when user enters special characters, like single quote symbol: `'`

My questions:

1. How can I deal with this on the server-side
2. If it is necessary to implement on JavaScript, then what characters have to be filtered     out?

Thank you.

Comment: Endusers have full control over JavaScript code. So absolutely don't do this kind of escaping in JavaScript. Use `PreparedStatement` in server side. Whatever framework you're using that doesn't support it, blame its authors. This is a **huge** design mistake in the framework as it puts doors wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 3):

Use prepared statement instead of composing SQL query string. Your way is vulnerable to [SQL Injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

If it is not possible to use PreparedStatements, then use java regular expression to remove special chars before passing this field value to SQL query.

There is [a post related to this task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374822/javascript-regexp-remove-all-special-characters).

Do not use javascript to filter out special symbols. It won't protect you from sql-injection attack. An attacker may forge his own form without validation javascript and attack your server.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameterized query for handle this kind of problems.

Comment: I think you are talking about PreparedStatement in java, But it is not possible for me to use the PreparedStatement as the framework does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is considered a very bad practice and may result in very bad things...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the invalid characters through basic validation using JavaScript and Regex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str= document.getElementById('mySearch').value;
str=str.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g,'');
alert(str);
</script>
```

But I agree with hkutluay, parametrized queries would be the better route.