# Regex to not allow special characters (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a following requirement to only allow capital letters and , in a javascript form . I am unsure on how to check for special characters and script tags . I have written the following code . I do not want to allow characters such as $,%,& etc .

```
var upperCase= new RegExp('[A-Z]');
var lowerCase= new RegExp('^[a-z]');
var numbers = new RegExp('^[0-9]');

if($(this).val().match(upperCase) && $(this).val().match(lowerCase) &&   $(this).val().match(numbers))  
{
    $("#passwordErrorMsg").html("OK")

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You can try `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test( str )` which will return true if any characters at not in a-Z, A-Z or 0-9 but note this will also treat `é` or similar character as rejected symbols

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Based on what you've given us, this may suit the bill. It will determine if any characters are not in character classes a-z, A-Z or 0-9 but note this will also treat `é` or similar characters as rejected symbols.

So if the value is 'test_' or 'test a' it will fail but it will pass for 'testa'. If you want it to accept spaces change the regex to `/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/`.

```
if(!/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test($(this).val())) {
    $("#passwordErrorMsg").html("OK");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be helpful.
[javascript regexp remove all special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374822/javascript-regexp-remove-all-special-characters)
 if the only characters you want are numbers, letters, and ',' then you just need to whitespice all characters that are not those

`$(this).val().replace(/[^\w\s\][^,]/gi, '')`

Answer (score 1):

This link may be helpful:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

It has a lot of information on JS Regexps.

For a dollar sign ($), the regexp syntax would be: `\$`. You need to escape the special character so it is read as a literal. The syntax would be the same for the other special characters, I believe.