# How can i validate Greek characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

I am using this snippet of a javascript code to validate alphabetic characters

```
   case "alpha_s":
            {
                ret = TestInputType(objValue, "([^A-Za-z\\s])", 
                strError, objValue.name + ": Only alphabetic characters and space 
                 allowed ");
                break;
            }
```

But i need the code to be able to validate Greek characters too. I tried doing this:

```
   case "alpha_s":
            {
                ret = TestInputType(objValue, "([^A-Za-z\\u0391-\\u03C9\\s])", strError, objValue.name + ": Only alphabetic characters and space allowed ");
                break;
}
```

But it had no result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - regex to remove special characters but also keep greek characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327302/javascript-regex-to-remove-special-characters-but-also-keep-greek-characters)

Comment: I tried the solutions given there, but nothing works unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine. There must be some problem elsewhere in your code.

Perhaps `case "alpha_s"` is only satisfied when there are no Greek characters. Or perhaps your `TestInputType()` function is getting confused by too many backslashes in the match string argument. Or maybe your document doesn't use Unicode.

The following snippet seems to work:

> ◽️ **Update (2021-04-28):** I've expanded the matching character class to include anything in the Unicode blocks `\u0370` to `\u03FF` (Greek and Coptic) and `\u1F00 to \u1FFF` (Greek Extended).

```js
function testChars() {
  var str = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  var r = document.getElementById("result");
  // Allow Roman alphabet characters (A-Z, a-z),
  // plus anything in the Unicode blocks \u0370 to
  // \u03FF (Greek and Coptic) and \u1F00 to \u1FFF
  // (Greek Extended):
  if (/^[A-Za-z\u0370-\u03FF\u1F00-\u1FFF]*$/.test(str)) {
    r.style.backgroundColor="green";
    r.style.color="white";
    r.innerHTML = "Looks OK";
  }
  else {
    r.style.backgroundColor="red";
    r.style.color="white";
    r.innerHTML = "Not OK!";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="testChars()"
  placeholder="Type something" size="40">
<span id="result" style="padding:.1em .5em 0; border-radius:.5em"></span>
```