# Removing all instances of a character from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I'm attempting to remove all instances of a given set of characters `£$€,.` from a string in jQuery/Javascript. I'm using the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function, however this only appears to remove a single instance of the character and not all of them.

For example consider the string:

```
1,500,00.00.$djdjd£10€10
```

I get back:

```
1500,0000.djdjd1010
```

As you can see, it only removes a single instance of each character. `£,` `$` and `€` are fine as there is only one of each in the string.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function validatePriceRange(value, min, max) {

    var replacements = ["£", "$", "€", ",", "."];

    $.each(replacements, function (index, item) {
        value = value.replace(item, "");
    });

    var value = parseInt(value, 10);

    return value >= min && value <= max;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8J3x/)

Can anyone spot what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) called with a string as first argument does only one replacement, while using a regular expression with flag `g` replaces all occurrences.

Using a regular expression, you can also avoid looping over an array and do it in one pass :

```
value = value.replace(/£|\$|€|,|\./g,'');
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks for the explanation on how replace works. I ignorantly assumed it worked in a similar way to how .`Replace()` works in `C#`.

Answer (score 1):

You are only cycling through your replacement array once and replace everytime the specific character. 
But **replace is only replacing the first occurance of a given string**.

> For a **replace all** method, look [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript).

Comment: yay, pointing at existing solutions rocks.  I might consider extending that solution by making ReplaceAll a prototype of String.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a function for it:

```
var validated = parseInt('1,500,00.00.$djdjd£10€10'.replace(/[£$€,.]/g,''), 10);
//=> 15000000
// or if you want the validated directly
var validated = function(min,max) {
                  var v = parseInt('1,500,00.00.$djdjd£10€10'
                                    .replace(/[£$€,.]/g,''), 10);
                  return v >= min && v <==max;
                }(1000, 200000); //=> false
```

The regular expression should be different if you want to include *all* digits in the string:

```
var validated = function(min,max) {
                  var v = parseInt('1,500,00.00.$djdjd£10€10'
                                    .replace(/[^\d]/g,''), 10);
                  //                           ^ replace non numbers
                  // v now is 150000001010
                  return v >= min && v <==max;
                }(1000, 200000); //=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex with the global flag, which will search and replace all instances

```
var replacements = ["£", "\\$", "€", ",", "\\."];
$.each(replacements, function (index, item) {
    value = value.replace(new RegExp(item, "g"), '');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S8HXk/)

Answer (score 0):

As already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374822/javascript-regexp-remove-all-special-characters) you could use the following regex that replaces all non characters and whitespaces with empty.

```
var value = "1,500,00.00.$djdjd£10€10"
value = value.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
```