# javascript cant remove invisible ascii character

Tags: javascript, replace, ascii

I have the following string:

`Backpacks‎`

Which if you copy and paste into the website http://asciivalue.com/ to examine each ascii char inside that string, you can see that after the text 'Backpacks' there is the ascii value: `&#8206;` , this value messes up when I try to write the string to a csv file, as it will get outputted as `Backpacksâ€Ž`

I have tried using .replace functions like `subcategoryStr.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");` and `replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g, '');` to remove any of these invisible nonstandard ascii but no luck, how can I remove this invisible character from a string in javascript?

Comment: Hmmm, that's a left-to-right unicode mark

Comment: `String.prototype.replace` returns a new string. Strings in JS are immutable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741455/how-to-remove-control-characters-from-string may be useful

Comment: tried using `subcategoryStr.replace(/[\u0000-\u001F\u007F-\u009F]/g, "");` but no change, still has the left to right unicode mark @SuperStormer

Comment: More directly: use `subcategoryStr = subcategoryStr.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");`

Comment: that works thanks @ASDFGerte