# String contains control character ERROR in script mediator - WSO2 EI 6.5.0

Tags: javascript, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm receiving JSON payload from customer, sometimes incoming payload value is lengthy and contains multiple special characters in some field eg (description).

Sample Payload:

```
    {
   "InstanceName":"clientDEV",
   "Direction":"InBound",
   "CustomerName":"client",
   "CustomerID":"6642671519xxx",
   "ObjectID":"c7cb6e97c399xxx",
   "ObjectName":"SCTASK0010101",
   "ObjectType":"Service Request",
   "OperationName":"UpdateObject",
   "ObjectData":{
      "description":"From: , Lene Bjørhei <Lene.Bjoerhei@client.com> , Sent: 19 August 2022 10:49 AM, To: Helpdesk <helpdesk@client.com>, Cc: Christensen, Helge <helge.christensen@client.com>, Subject: Power BI, , Hi, , , I have two names in Power BI, where the one marked with red is wrong. , , On the same list, Hanne Topland don, t work in client anymore and has no claims attached to her in PBI, and Kine Haaland is not in our department and has no claims here either. , ,    Kind reclients, Lene Bjørhei ,   Team leader,   P&I and Offshore Energy claims, client AS, o: +47 39 00 00 00  , m: +47 24 00 05 11, e: lene.bjoerhei@client.com",
      "cmdb_ci":"",
      "number":"SCTASK0010101",
      "contact_type":"Email",
      "state":"-5",
      "sys_created_on":"2022-08-19 10:05:39",
      "sys_created_by":"Maria@client.com",
      "priority":"4",
      "category":"inquiry",
      "subcategory":"internal application",
      "short_description":"Application - Power BI Claim handler names",
      "assignment_group":"Cognizant ICT Services - Service Desk",
      "caller":"Lene Bjørhei ",
      "close_code":"",
      "close_notes":"undefined",
      "comments":"",
      "work_notes":"Work notes: From: Christensen, Helge <helge.christensen@client.com>\n Sent: Monday, August 22, 2022 7:33 AM\n To: , Lene Bjørhei <Lene.Bjoerhei.@client.com>\n Cc: Helpdesk <helpdesk@client.com>\n Subject: FW: Power BI\n  \n Good morning Lene,\n \n Your old and misspelled name has been removed from the data source, sorry for the inconvenience.\n \n Kr\n Helge\n \n \n \n Additional comments: ",
      "u_queue":"",
      "on_hold_reason":"Awaiting Customer IT SPOC"
   }
}
```

API Code Snippet:

```
    <property expression="json-eval($.text)" name="received_payload" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property expression="base64Decode(get-property('received_payload'))" name="decoded_payload" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('decoded_payload')" name="DATA:DecodedPayload" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[var customer_payload = mc.getProperty("decoded_payload");
var myJSON = JSON.parse(customer_payload);
//remianing business flow
]]></script>
```

Facing `String contains control character ERROR` in script mediator when some special character comes in the payload.

Log:

```
    [2022-08-22 05:29:38,840] [-1234] [] [pool-58-thread-68583] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator} -  The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: String contains control character (<Unknown Source>#2) in <Unknown Source> at line number 2
    at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:394)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:289)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:257)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectInbound(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:445)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.amazonsqs.AmazonSQSPollingConsumer.injectMessage(AmazonSQSPollingConsumer.java:267)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.amazonsqs.AmazonSQSPollingConsumer.poll(AmazonSQSPollingConsumer.java:206)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.amazonsqs.AmazonSQSPollingConsumer.poll(AmazonSQSPollingConsumer.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.generic.GenericTask.taskExecute(GenericTask.java:41)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.common.InboundTask.execute(InboundTask.java:45)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskAdapter.execute(NTaskAdapter.java:98)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: String contains control character (<Unknown Source>#2)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJSON.parse(NativeJSON.java:112)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJSON.execIdCall(NativeJSON.java:88)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__79771._c_script_0(<Unknown Source>:2)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__79771.call(<Unknown Source>)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__79771.call(<Unknown Source>)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__79771.exec(<Unknown Source>)
    at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:55)
    ... 21 more
```

Found [this](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-invalid-control-character-at#:%7E:text=Control%20characters%20are%20those%20with,trying%20to%20parse%20is%20valid.), But not sure this will help or not.

How to handle this ? is there any way to allow this characters in payload?

Comment: Please do not add images of your exceptions. Also, make sure you add the full stack trace.

Comment: I meant, that rather than adding images of errors, try adding the text instead. So please add your exception to the question.

Comment: Hi @ycr
Payload which cause issue and ERROR Log details updated as u suggested. Kindly have a look on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this has to do anything with the Payload. The error indicated that it detected control characters in your script. Also, I don't see any control characters in the shared JSON payload. If your JSON is valid [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) it should work.

So double-check the content of your script, maybe you can start with something simple and try to expand. Also, instead of `language="js"` try to use `<script language="nashornJs">` instead.

If you really think the error is generated due to the payload, try to replace the control characters before parsing the string to a JSON. Something like below,

```
var customer_payload = mc.getProperty("decoded_payload");
customer_payload.replace(/[\u0000-\u001F\u007F-\u009F]/g, "")
var myJSON = JSON.parse(customer_payload);
```

**Update**

After looking at the full Stacktrace the error seems to be caused by the payload. It's thrown somewhere [here](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/8fac71800f1bb65500f7c38fb1dcf2a706b47e36/src/org/mozilla/javascript/json/JsonParser.java#L184) in the source. So replacing the control character should work.

Comment: Hi @ycr,

Thank you for response. As you suggested, will do necessary changes in script mediator, could you please share some more information like what are all characters has been included by giving expression(\u0000-\u001F\u007F-\u009F]/g) in replace functionality.

Comment: @Justin please take a look at the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51602415/2627018

Comment: @Justin did you try the above options?

Comment: Hi @ycr,
Thanks for your patience, the server is in power-off cycle, will let u know the results soon.