# How to return JSON call as string without special characters

Tags: jquery, json

I am looking to return a files contents and I am using a webservice and JSON to do this.

I have managed to return the contents but it is not in the format I want it to be in.

I need the top text area to be in the same format as the textarea on the bottom:

[image]

[image]

I need to to display the `\n` as a new line rather than just remove it from the string.

Current code (ignore alerts, only for my own testing purposes):

```
function CallWebService(CSSFile) {
    var stringToDisplay = "";
    var webMethod = "../services/BrokerAdmin/CSSComparison.asmx/GetFileContents";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: webMethod,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            CSSFile: CSSFile
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {},
        error: function(e) {
            alert("Error = " + e.responseText);
        },
        complete: function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
            if (JSON.parse(msg.responseText).d.toString() != "" || JSON.parse(msg.responseText).d.toString() != null) {
                alert("msg.responseText = " + msg.responseText);
                $('#ctl00_BodyContent_elm2').val(msg.responseText);
            } else if (JSON.parse(msg.responseText).Message.toString() == "" || JSON.parse(msg.responseText).d.toString() == null) {
                alert("YOU LOSE!");
            } else {
                alert("TRY AGAIN");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Suggest you make these images a bit larger.  Hard to read.

Comment: @kaz hopefully that will be a bit clearer

Comment: Parse this JSON using `JSON.parse(that_text)` then grab `parsed_json.d`. Post your code.

Comment: @SalmanA it was this answer that provided me with the information to answer my own question.  If you want to give a more detailed answer I will mark as "The Accepted Answer"?

Answer (score 1):

Solution found!

```
complete: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
            if (JSON.parse(msg.responseText).d.toString() != "" || JSON.parse(msg.responseText).d.toString() != null) {
                alert("msg.responseText = " + msg.responseText);
                $('#ctl00_BodyContent_elm2').val(msg.responseText);
            }
            else if (JSON.parse(msg.responseText).Message.toString() == "" || JSON.parse(msg.responseText).d.toString() == null) {
                alert("YOU LOSE!");
            }
            else {
                alert("TRY AGAIN");
            }
        }
```

In my original code I was able to change the val() being passed to my elm2.  Code change below:

```
complete: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
                if (JSON.parse(msg.responseText).d.toString() != "" || JSON.parse(msg.responseText).d.toString() != null) {
                    $('#ctl00_BodyContent_elm2').val(JSON.parse(msg.responseText).d.toString());
                }
                else if (JSON.parse(msg.responseText).Message.toString() == "" || JSON.parse(msg.responseText).d.toString() == null) {
                    alert("Nothing in CSS file.");
                }
                else {
                }
            }
```

All now displaying as it should :)  Thanks for everyones help!

Answer (score 0):

try the solution in 
[javascript regexp remove all special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374822/javascript-regexp-remove-all-special-characters)

take you json return and replace special characters:

```
var desired_json = json_text.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
```

It could be that you want only to replace new lines:

```
var desired_json = json_text.replace(/\n/gi, '');
```

EDIT: to show the special characters as line breaks...

```
 var desired_json = json_text.replace(/\r\n/gi, '<br>');
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work.  It replaced all the special characters but I need to to display the \n as a new line rather than just remove it from the string.  I should probably add this to the original question to make it a bit clearer as to what I am trying to do

Comment: you may need to replace the \n with <br/> to show it in a HTML page.
json_text.replace(/\n/gi, '<br>');

Answer (score 0):

ignoring the alerts i take that `$('#ctl00_BodyContent_elm2').val(msg.responseText);` is the actual code to output the results? what kind of element is '#ctl00_BodyContent_elm2'?

try adding some `<textarea>` in your html and in ajax complete add

```
$('textarea').val( JSON.parse(json).d );
```

is that what you're looking for?

Comment: It was in a textarea but it was how I was parsing the JSON call that was causing the problem.  See the marked answer for more info if you wish