# How to prevent emoji shortcuts

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, emoji

I am having issues preventing the browser from creating emojis inside of 'textarea' and 'input' elements, by triggering shortcuts like 'alt + 1', 'alt + 2'.

This code prohibits any interaction with said elements, but 'alt + 1' still creates smileys. Tested on Chrome and Edge. Am I missing something?

```
'use strict';
(() => {
  document.onkeydown = document.onkeypress = document.onkeyup = ev => {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9Lr0hays/1/

*Note: I don't want to interact with the elements directly (using selectors).*

I am talking about these symbols:
http://www.alt-codes.net/

Related: [Disable Alt Codes/Characters with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075988/disable-alt-codes-characters-with-javascript)

Comment: It doesn't create anything in my chrome browser... nor IE or Firefox

Comment: Alt+1 is not creating any emoji

Comment: Just found out it only happens on the num pad.

Comment: Problem occurs on all tested systems (running windows 10)

Comment: Side note: the smiley is created when releasing the alt key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very bad mistake. I wrote `document.keypress` instead of `document.onkeypress` in the fiddle (the snippet was correct).

Working solution:

```
'use strict';
(() => {
  document.onkeypress = ev => false;
})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9Lr0hays/3/

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to this problem is check key codes.

```
<input type="text" id="number" onkeypress="return iskey(event);" />
<script>
function iskey(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var theVal = theEvent.target.value;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;

    key = String.fromCharCode(key);

    if (key.length == 0) return;
        if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
        return false;
}
</script>
```

Working here: https://jsfiddle.net/1569atLz/23/

Comment: This does not seem to work. Also: ReturnValue is non-standard and deprecated.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/returnValue

Comment: Yes because it also handels window.event and we ignore double keys when key.length is 0

Comment: Could you please update the answer, using no direct selectors (as stated in the question)?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, you helped me find out what I did wrong (see answer below).