# JS Form validation, invalid characters?

Tags: javascript, validation

Trying to validate my form and set up a variable for invalid characters, but I'm having trouble getting them recognized because they're just a bunch of symbols? -

```
function validation(){
        var Name =
        document.getElementById("name").value;
        var Email = document.getElementByID("email").value;
        var invalidSymbol = /[\~\`\!\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\+\{\}\:\\\;\"\'\<\>\?\,\]/;

        if Name == ""{
            alert("Please enter your name");
            document.getElementById("Name").focus();
            return false;
        }else if (Email == "" | | Email.indexOf("@")<1 || Email.lastIndexOf("@")+2 || Email.lastIndexOf(".")+2>=Email.indexOf("@").length || Email.match(invalidSymbol)){
            alert ("Please enter a valid e-mail address");
            document.getElementById("email").focus();
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var desired = stringToReplace.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
> ```
>
> As was mentioned in the comments it's easier to do this as a whitelist
>   - replace the characters which aren't in your safelist.
>
> The caret (^) character is the negation of the set [...], gi say
>   global and case-insensitive (the latter is a bit redundant but I
>   wanted to mention it) and the safelist in this example is digits, word
>   characters, underscores (\w) and whitespace (\s).

As stated  here:
[javascript regexp remove all special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374822/javascript-regexp-remove-all-special-characters)
by
[annakata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13018/annakata)