# Javascript remove all characters from string which are not numbers, letters and whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

With JavaScript I would like to remove all characters from a string which are not numbers, letters and whitespace.  So remove characters like `'%#$&@*` so something like:

> Player's got to * play! #justsaying

would become:

> Players got to play justsaying

How can I do this, I'm not sure about regex.

Comment: Maybe `[^0-9a-zA-Z ]`? with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @chris85 said, you can use the regular expression `[^0-9a-z-A-Z]` to replace all the characters that are not letters, numbers, or whitespace.

Here is a function that will do what you want:

```
function clean(str) {
    return str.replace(/[^0-9a-z-A-Z ]/g, "").replace(/ +/, " ")
}
```

The second replace call is needed to remove the runs of extra whitespace that are made from removing a character that is between spaces.

Comment: The whitespace should be quantified. With an uneven number of whitespaces this would still have multiple whitespaces.

Comment: I added your suggestion

Answer (score 4):

Use `replace`

```
string.replace(/[^A-Z\d\s]/gi, '')
```

Note the two flags at the end of the regex

`g` - stands for global, and means that every such instance of the regular expression will be found

`i` - stands for case insensitive. That means it will match both lower case and uppercase characters

Playing with your string, it returns this output

```
"Players got to  play justsaying"
```

To transform two or more whitespace characters into a single whitespace, you could hain another `replace` method to the existing ones.

```
string.replace(/[^A-Z\d\s]/gi, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
```

The key here is the `+` character, which finds one or more.

It's probably possible to do it more efficiently, but I'm an amateur in Regex.

Comment: thanks, is there a way I could remove double white spaces, so a double white space would become a single white space?

Comment: @Holy same concept. use replace to replace double whitespace with whatever you want. Richard Hamilton gave you a great answer, and I think you would benefit greatly from learning how to use `string.replace` vs. asking people how to do it

Comment: Modified the original answer

Comment: I'd use a space, not `\s`, this will convert all new lines to spaces as well.

Answer (score 2):

I also added sign `'` to regex because you have word `Player's`, so here my code:

```
var str = "Player's got to * play! #justsaying";
var result = str.replace(/[^a-z\d\s']/gi, '');
```

Comment: @chris85 Yes, you're right `\w` also will mach `_`. I've updated my answer. Thank you!

Comment: It also included numbers so the `\d` was redundant.

Answer (score 1):

**ORIGINAL TEXT**

```
Player's got to * play! #justsaying
```

**REGEXP**

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9\s])
```

**RESULT**

```
Players got to  play justsaying
```

**TEST IT**

```js
const regex = /([^a-zA-Z0-9\s])/gm;
const str = `Player's got to * play! #justsaying`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

**See:** https://regex101.com/r/BYSDwz/4

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
var text = "Player's got to * play! #justsaying";
var result = text.replace(/[^A-Z\d\s]/gi,'');
console.log(result);
```

Read more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

This is how you might go about matching the characters you are interested in removing...

```
[^\d\w\s]
```

NB: That you should use the global modifier

Tested here: https://regex101.com/r/yilfcn/1
Refer to this post regarding how to apply it: [javascript regexp remove all special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374822/javascript-regexp-remove-all-special-characters)

Comment: \w = "any word character", so I'm saying match anything that isn't a number a word or a space.

Comment: No, it is, numbers, letters, or underscores. http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

Comment: Oh I see!  Thanks that's useful to know.