# Javascript - Ignore punctuation and spaces in a Switch Statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a page with a question. The user will have to type the answer to that question in a textbox. I am using a switch statement to generate different feedback to different answers. I already managed to make it case insensitive.

Is there a way to also make it ignore punctuation and spaces?

This is the code I have:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var text;
    var answers = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toLowerCase();
    switch (answers) {
        case "superman":
            text = "That is correct!";
            break;
        case "batman":
            text = "You must be kidding me...";
            break;
        default:
            text = "Wrong answer."
    }
    document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p>Who is Clark Kent?</p>
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Answer</button>
<p id="comment"></p>
```

I would like it to accept all the following answers as correct, without having to add extra cases:

"Superman", "superman", "Super Man", "Super man", "Super-Man!", "Super-man"...

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374822/remove-all-special-characters-with-regexp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regex to ignore everything else that is not an alphabet.

```
function myFunction() {
    var text;
    var answers = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toLowerCase();
    answers = answers.replace(/[^a-z]/g, "");
    switch (answers) {
        case "superman":
            text = "That is correct!";
            break;
        case "batman":
            text = "You must be kidding me...";
            break;
        default:
            text = "Wrong answer."
    }
    document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: @Barmar was already on it before you commented. Thanks for pointing it out though

Comment: Thank you a lot. I am not familiar with regex, but this works perfectly.

Comment: @MikeMichaels you can read more about it in an interactive playground here: https://regexr.com/
Also, please mark the answer accepted if it works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You could match only letters and omit unwanted character. Then take convert to lower case.

```js
function myFunction() {
    function getLetters(s) { return s.match(/[a-z]/gi).join('').toLowerCase(); }

    var text;
    var answers = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toLowerCase();
    switch (getLetters(answers)) {
        case "superman":
            text = "That is correct!";
            break;
        case "batman":
            text = "You must be kidding me...";
            break;
        default:
            text = "Wrong answer."
    }
    document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p>Who is Clark Kent?</p>
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Answer</button>
<p id="comment"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
var desired = stringToReplace.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase();
```

Comment: You also need to worry about case.

Comment: Yeah Thanks :)  @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @Aagam Jain, I am sorry for such a noob question, I am still a beginner. But where should I put that? I tried placing that after "var text;" but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: answers = answers.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''); put this before switch statement. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, mate!