# Array on number from string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, numbers

I am trying to get an array of numbers from a string that does not have a token to use as a split.

Example:

```
var myString = 'someString5oneMoreString6';
```

Expected result :

```
var result = [5, 6];
```

How to archive this with javascript before ES2015?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all special characters with RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374822/remove-all-special-characters-with-regexp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract ("get") a number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/extract-get-a-number-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match all digits and convert the result to numbers.

```js
var string = 'someString5oneMoreString6',
    array = string.match(/\d+/g);

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) array[i] = +array[i];

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `split` by regex and `map` to process.

```js
var str = 'someString5oneMoreString6';

const array = str.split(/[a-zA-Z]+/).filter(x => x).map(x => Number(x));

console.log(array);
```