# Add specific symbol to reg ex javascript

Tags: javascript

i have regex - `current.replace(/([^0-9]+)/gi, '');`
How i can add here `₽` specific symbol? im trying `current.replace(/([^0-9₽]+)/gi, '');` But this not working...

Comment: It really depends on what you want to achieve. Please provide an example input and the desired output. "But this is not working..." is not a useful problem description.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374822/remove-all-special-characters-with-regexp

Comment: I need to remove everything from the value except the spaces and the rub submbol  ₽

Comment: if you want to remove everything bar the spaces and ₽ - what's the deal with `0-9`? you want to keep numbers as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^0-9₽]` means "NOT 0-9 or ₽".
To remove everything but keep spaces and ₽ do:
`.replace(/[^ ₽]/gi, ''))`

```js
let string = "h 3 l l 0 ₽ h 4 l l 0";

console.log(".replace(/₽/gi, '') Will remove ₽:")
console.log(string + " > " + string.replace(/₽/gi, ''));
console.log(".replace(/[^0-9₽]/gi, '') Will remove everything that is not 0-9 or ₽:")
console.log(string + " > " + string.replace(/[^0-9₽]/gi, ''));
console.log(".replace(/[^ ₽]/gi, '') Will remove everything that is not SPACE or ₽:")
console.log(string + " > " + string.replace(/[^ ₽]/gi, ''));
```