# reject if file name contains non english character

Tags: javascript

am trying to upload file which file name contains only in english character with symbol or number ,my problem is if my file name contains **english with chinese character** then i need to validate it and need to show alert message that file name should'nt be in non english character

can anybody send me this code

Comment: Why do you care? You should never use user uploaded filenames for anything anyway. The contents of the file are important, not how the user labeled it on his computer.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters

Comment: client will send one mail with attachment my job is i need to read mail with attachment and i need it to store it in my server, if my attachment contains no english character file name then i need to show alert message

Comment: Again, why?! I'd find this highly annoying.

Comment: yes i need to store that attachment first in my folder when i trying to save this file i need to read file name here exactly my code is failing , if i show a error messege that i can allow only english character file name,

Comment: Don't save the file under the original filename. Never! Make up a new random filename.

Comment: @deceze: I plan to do the same for a website (i.e. use the original file names on the server, appending a sequential number if duplicate). Wondering why you consider it a bad practice.

Comment: @Salman Because the user supplied filename may a) already exist on the server and b) be invalid as a filename. You need to a) check if the name already exists and add numbers (as you say) and b) make sure it's a valid filename and replace/escape invalid characters. So most of the time, you're not using the original filename anyway. Why bother with all the checking and escaping then? Just generate a random unique filename and be done with it. Save the original filename in a database if you really need it later.

Answer (score 4):

Get the value of the `file` input, and match it against the regex `\w`

But you should not disallow this. You should instead rename the file after it is uploaded. The user may upload a file with a name valid in his OS, but invalid on the server OS. You can still store the original filename is a database, if needed.

Comment: i need to show error message if they trying to upload file name contain non english character file

Comment: if(filename != regex[\w]) alert("non english character not allowed"); is it correct

Comment: @vijay `filename.matches(/\w/g)`

Comment: if(fileName.matches(/\w/g)) { alert("english"); } else { alert("non english character"); } its showing error

Comment: object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: what is `fileName` ? how did you obtain it.

Comment: from <input type="file" name="txtFile" id="txtFile" /> acessing this id in my javascript function var fileName = document.getElementById("txtFile").value; and the file name is in english with chinesecharacter file name is Cisco-S11-POA1800005815-Inv04736851-100919重做没有.pdf

Comment: @vijay - try this on firefox, debug with firebug

Comment: @Bozho no my application supports only in internet explorer any it is my comany rule

Comment: @vijay what a crappy company then ;) seriously. Then use some IE debug tool - I think there were some. Or you can still use firefox for debug purposes.

Comment: do u have any idea about this [\u4E00-\u9FFF]  can i use this to check if(filename.match[\u4E00-\u9FFF])

Comment: var str="Cisco-S11-POA1800005815-Inv04736851-100919重做没有.pdf"; 
var patt1=[\u4E00-\u9FFF];
if(str.match(patt1))
{
alert("filename is english");
}
please check this can i use like this

Comment: any alternate method can u send me all english character symbol small cap regular expression i will check opposite to that

Comment: `\w` means all english characters. The problem is not in the regex. Debug your code.

Comment: if i check with all special character  i hope my problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm going to come out and say that you should probably just match the filename to your alphanumeric regex, and throw out a generic error if it doesn't match. However, if you are dead set on giving a specific warning for Chinese characters, use the following regex:

```
[\u4E00-\u9FFF]
```

A sharp eye may also recognize this as a subset of Japanese (since Japanese calls the Chinese character set 'Kanji').

```
if(preg_match("[\u4E00-\u9FFF]+", $filename))
  { echo "Chinese characters found in filename."; }
```

Comment: how to check this if (filename != [\u4E00-\u9FFF] )

Comment: how to check this if (filename != regex[\u4E00-\u9FFF] ) { alert(""); is this ok

Answer (score 0):

this could work for non english characters

```
[^A-Za-z0-9_,.@\(\)\&\+\-\!\#\$\%\^\*\;\\\/\|\<\>'":\?\=\s]+
```

Answer (score 0):

get filename with this code:

```js
function checkname(event) {
 var fullPath = document.getElementById('file').value;
  var filename;
 if (fullPath) {
  var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
  filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);
  if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
   filename = filename.substring(1);
  }
 }

  if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9$@$!%*?&#^-_-. +]+$/.test(filename)) {
  console.log("error: "+filename);
  return;
 } else {
    console.log("ok");
  }

};
```

```html
<form action="" method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input type='file' id='file' name='file' onchange="checkname(event);">
  <input type='submit' value='upload'>
</form>
```

and use this code for validation:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9$@$!%*?&#^-_. +]+$/.test(filename);
```

if you want dont allow use characters use this:

```
 /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(filename);
```