# Jquery: Replace string with only the first word

Tags: javascript

I have been looking everywhere and can't find this..

I got a string and I want to replace the whole string with only the first word.

for example:

String: "hello world"

New String: "hello"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var s = "hello world"
s = s.replace(/(\w+).*/,"$1");
```

that'll do it.

Comment: Damn NICE! I gotta figure this out. Do you know a table where each of the symbols mean you used to create that?

Comment: @GermanMan [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) is a good resource

Comment: This is working good.. But this doesen't work with other language words :-(

Comment: @Anand Interesting.  Do you have an example you could share?  As I understand it, `\w` should match non-whitespace characters.  It shouldn't have a problem with other languages, but I could be completely wrong there.

Comment: @Anand  Looks like regex does have issues with multilingual support: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters.  There are a few suggestions in that thread that might help you.

Comment: In Söderhamn, when I used the above string, it outputs S instead of Söderhamn.

Comment: @Anand based on the question I linked, this may work for you: `"Söderhamn lorem ipsum".replace(/([\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]+).*/,"$1");`.  I don't know enough about the unicode sets to confirm for certain that this covers all scenarios, however.

Answer (score 5):

The quickest and easiest way is to split the string into an array based on spaces, then set it to be the first one.

```
var theString = "hello world";
theString = theString.split(" ")[0];
alert(theString); // alerts "hello"
```