# How to check if the first character is a letter

Tags: javascript, regex, internationalization

How can I determine whether the first character of a string is a letter, regardless of the alphabet?

```
regExpIsLetter  = /^\w/;
regExpIsLetter.test('Å') -> false
regExpIsLetter.test('ç') -> false
regExpIsLetter.test('A') -> true
regExpIsLetter.test('š') -> false !! (czech)
regExpIsLetter.test('ф') -> false !! (cyrilic)
regExpIsLetter.test('ڂ') -> false !! (arabic)
```

=================

Based on answers I found "solution". It's the 'simple' regex:

```
regExpIsLetter = /^[\u0041-\u005a\u0061-\u007a\u00aa-\u00aa\u00b5-\u00b5\u00ba-\u00ba\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u0236\u0250-\u02c1\u02c6-\u02d1\u02e0-\u02e4\u02ee-\u02ee\u037a-\u037a\u0386-\u0386\u0388-\u038a\u038c-\u038c\u038e-\u03a1\u03a3-\u03ce\u03d0-\u03f5\u03f7-\u03fb\u0400-\u0481\u048a-\u04ce\u04d0-\u04f5\u04f8-\u04f9\u0500-\u050f\u0531-\u0556\u0559-\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05d0-\u05ea\u05f0-\u05f2\u0621-\u063a\u0640-\u064a\u066e-\u066f\u0671-\u06d3\u06d5-\u06d5\u06e5-\u06e6\u06ee-\u06ef\u06fa-\u06fc\u06ff-\u06ff\u0710-\u0710\u0712-\u072f\u074d-\u074f\u0780-\u07a5\u07b1-\u07b1\u0904-\u0939\u093d-\u093d\u0950-\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0985-\u098c\u098f-\u0990\u0993-\u09a8\u09aa-\u09b0\u09b2-\u09b2\u09b6-\u09b9\u09bd-\u09bd\u09dc-\u09dd\u09df-\u09e1\u09f0-\u09f1\u0a05-\u0a0a\u0a0f-\u0a10\u0a13-\u0a28\u0a2a-\u0a30\u0a32-\u0a33\u0a35-\u0a36\u0a38-\u0a39\u0a59-\u0a5c\u0a5e-\u0a5e\u0a72-\u0a74\u0a85-\u0a8d\u0a8f-\u0a91\u0a93-\u0aa8\u0aaa-\u0ab0\u0ab2-\u0ab3\u0ab5-\u0ab9\u0abd-\u0abd\u0ad0-\u0ad0\u0ae0-\u0ae1\u0b05-\u0b0c\u0b0f-\u0b10\u0b13-\u0b28\u0b2a-\u0b30\u0b32-\u0b33\u0b35-\u0b39\u0b3d-\u0b3d\u0b5c-\u0b5d\u0b5f-\u0b61\u0b71-\u0b71\u0b83-\u0b83\u0b85-\u0b8a\u0b8e-\u0b90\u0b92-\u0b95\u0b99-\u0b9a\u0b9c-\u0b9c\u0b9e-\u0b9f\u0ba3-\u0ba4\u0ba8-\u0baa\u0bae-\u0bb5\u0bb7-\u0bb9\u0c05-\u0c0c\u0c0e-\u0c10\u0c12-\u0c28\u0c2a-\u0c33\u0c35-\u0c39\u0c60-\u0c61\u0c85-\u0c8c\u0c8e-\u0c90\u0c92-\u0ca8\u0caa-\u0cb3\u0cb5-\u0cb9\u0cbd-\u0cbd\u0cde-\u0cde\u0ce0-\u0ce1\u0d05-\u0d0c\u0d0e-\u0d10\u0d12-\u0d28\u0d2a-\u0d39\u0d60-\u0d61\u0d85-\u0d96\u0d9a-\u0db1\u0db3-\u0dbb\u0dbd-\u0dbd\u0dc0-\u0dc6\u0e01-\u0e30\u0e32-\u0e33\u0e40-\u0e46\u0e81-\u0e82\u0e84-\u0e84\u0e87-\u0e88\u0e8a-\u0e8a\u0e8d-\u0e8d\u0e94-\u0e97\u0e99-\u0e9f\u0ea1-\u0ea3\u0ea5-\u0ea5\u0ea7-\u0ea7\u0eaa-\u0eab\u0ead-\u0eb0\u0eb2-\u0eb3\u0ebd-\u0ebd\u0ec0-\u0ec4\u0ec6-\u0ec6\u0edc-\u0edd\u0f00-\u0f00\u0f40-\u0f47\u0f49-\u0f6a\u0f88-\u0f8b\u1000-\u1021\u1023-\u1027\u1029-\u102a\u1050-\u1055\u10a0-\u10c5\u10d0-\u10f8\u1100-\u1159\u115f-\u11a2\u11a8-\u11f9\u1200-\u1206\u1208-\u1246\u1248-\u1248\u124a-\u124d\u1250-\u1256\u1258-\u1258\u125a-\u125d\u1260-\u1286\u1288-\u1288\u128a-\u128d\u1290-\u12ae\u12b0-\u12b0\u12b2-\u12b5\u12b8-\u12be\u12c0-\u12c0\u12c2-\u12c5\u12c8-\u12ce\u12d0-\u12d6\u12d8-\u12ee\u12f0-\u130e\u1310-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u131e\u1320-\u1346\u1348-\u135a\u13a0-\u13f4\u1401-\u166c\u166f-\u1676\u1681-\u169a\u16a0-\u16ea\u1700-\u170c\u170e-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176c\u176e-\u1770\u1780-\u17b3\u17d7-\u17d7\u17dc-\u17dc\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18a8\u1900-\u191c\u1950-\u196d\u1970-\u1974\u1d00-\u1d6b\u1e00-\u1e9b\u1ea0-\u1ef9\u1f00-\u1f15\u1f18-\u1f1d\u1f20-\u1f45\u1f48-\u1f4d\u1f50-\u1f57\u1f59-\u1f59\u1f5b-\u1f5b\u1f5d-\u1f5d\u1f5f-\u1f7d\u1f80-\u1fb4\u1fb6-\u1fbc\u1fbe-\u1fbe\u1fc2-\u1fc4\u1fc6-\u1fcc\u1fd0-\u1fd3\u1fd6-\u1fdb\u1fe0-\u1fec\u1ff2-\u1ff4\u1ff6-\u1ffc\u2071-\u2071\u207f-\u207f\u2102-\u2102\u2107-\u2107\u210a-\u2113\u2115-\u2115\u2119-\u211d\u2124-\u2124\u2126-\u2126\u2128-\u2128\u212a-\u212d\u212f-\u2131\u2133-\u2139\u213d-\u213f\u2145-\u2149\u3005-\u3006\u3031-\u3035\u303b-\u303c\u3041-\u3096\u309d-\u309f\u30a1-\u30fa\u30fc-\u30ff\u3105-\u312c\u3131-\u318e\u31a0-\u31b7\u31f0-\u31ff\u3400-\u4db5\u4e00-\u9fa5\ua000-\ua48c\uac00-\ud7a3\uf900-\ufa2d\ufa30-\ufa6a\ufb00-\ufb06\ufb13-\ufb17\ufb1d-\ufb1d\ufb1f-\ufb28\ufb2a-\ufb36\ufb38-\ufb3c\ufb3e-\ufb3e\ufb40-\ufb41\ufb43-\ufb44\ufb46-\ufbb1\ufbd3-\ufd3d\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufdf0-\ufdfb\ufe70-\ufe74\ufe76-\ufefc\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a\uff66-\uffbe\uffc2-\uffc7\uffca-\uffcf\uffd2-\uffd7\uffda-\uffdc]/
regExpIsLetter  = /^\w/;
regExpIsLetter.test('Å') -> true
regExpIsLetter.test('ç') -> true
regExpIsLetter.test('A') -> true
regExpIsLetter.test('š') -> true
regExpIsLetter.test('ф') -> true
regExpIsLetter.test('ڂ') -> true
regExpIsLetter.test('4') -> false
```

Groovy code to generate regex:

```
def range = false;
def rangeStart = 0;
System.err.printf('[');
for(int i = 0; i < 65536; ++i) {
    def isLetter = Character.isLetter(i);
    if (!range && isLetter) {
        rangeStart = i;
        range = true;
    }
    else if (range && !isLetter) {
        range = false;
        if( rangeStart != i - 1 ) {
            System.err.printf('\\u%04x-\\u%04x', rangeStart, i - 1);
        }
        else {
            System.err.printf('\\u%04x', rangeStart);
        }

    }
}
System.err.printf(']');
```

Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript's character classes are not Unicode aware; see http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-and-unicode

Comment: There are letters above the 65536 codepoint, so I'm afraid you'll have to run across the whole Unicode range (up to 1114109) to get the complete picture!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of JavaScript's character classes are not Unicode-aware, per ECMA-262. Have a look at http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-and-unicode for more information.

For great JavaScript / Unicode resources, I can't answer any better than [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/873600/283078) to a slightly different question.

**EDIT**: Checking with PHP, which has the `/u` modifier for checking strings as UTF-8, all of your examples above pass:

```
var_dump(preg_match("/^\w/u", "ڂ")); // etc
```

Comment: /^[\u0041-\u005a\u0061-\u00 ... ffda-\uffdc]/.test('Š') -> true

Comment: Yeah, Š is U+0160, and [it is a letter](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0160/index.htm) according to the standard... Looks like an issue with my terminal. I'll remove the gibberish from above :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for unicode regex in Javascript. However it does support character like `\unnnn-\ummmm`. For your code you can do something like this:

```
regExpIsLetter = /^[\u0000-\u007F\u0080-\u00FF\u0100-\u017F\u0180-\u024F\u0370-\u03FF\u0400-\u04FF\u0500-\u052F\u0590-\u05FF\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F]/;
```

This will also match punctuation ascii characters like `$`, `#`, `@` etc.

To build your custom range, you can visit [this page](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block).