# Allowing non-latin characters with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression to match non-english characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)

I am using this regex to limit some characters.
I wanted to change this to allow all latin and non-latin letters but i think regex is not my think : )

```
String.prototype.isText2 = function () {return /^[\.\-\w\s&']*$/.test(this)}
```

This regex only allows latin chars and `'` and `&` i think.

How can i make it allow non-latin letters ? (like these ç,ü,ğ,ş and chinese,japanese, arabic)

Comment: perhaps something like `\u0000-\u007f`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`XRegExp`](http://xregexp.com/plugins/). This supports Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to work with unicode values. Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters) previous SO thread for more information.