# grep to only match whole words with non-english characters

Tags: regex, bash, grep, character, regex-lookarounds

I want to only grep for a whole word. The problem is a file contains non-english characters, so `grep -w` doesn't work (f.e. matches "aąbcć" when searching for "bc"). I can't write any working regex with lookaround either. Can anybody help me?

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618647/allowing-non-latin-characters-with-regex

Comment: What is your locale? `env | grep 'LC\|LANG'`

Comment: `LC_MESSAGES=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=pl_PL.UTF-8
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=pl_PL:en
LC_CTYPE=pl_PL.UTF-8
`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use word boundaries in grep:

```
grep "\<bc\>" file
```

Comment: `echo -e "aąbcć\nbc" | grep "\<bc\>"` gives me two matches. One thing changed: first line isn't colored anymore.

Comment: Very strange since I am getting only 1 match from this command.

Comment: But I am testing it on `Mac OSX`.

Comment: See this bug report on this matter: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=720482

Answer (score 0):

Requiring GNU grep: `grep -P '(^|\s)\Kbc(?=$|\s)' file`

Using awk, I wonder if this would work:

```
awk -v word="bc" '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == word) {print; break}}' file
```

Comment: I need whole lines where word exists.

Comment: Unfortunately, "bc," doesn't pass the test in awk solution.