# JavaScript regex for validating for alphanumeric characters,all international characters (Japanese, Chinese, Russian etc)

Tags: javascript, .net, regex, asp-classic

One of my project requirements is to validate a data field(text box from web page). I need to allow alpha numeric characters in all foreign languages (japanese,chinese,korean,russian,latin american characters etc). And avoid special characters.

I am using the expression `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/` (javascript, asp .net page)

Many blogs I have read and not able to correctly understand what exactly I have to do here. I can't add any addons or plugins and have to use the available functionality of regex.

How do regex engine recognize other language characters (esp. Unicode)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match non-english characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match non-English characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use `Unicode` regular expressions. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters) previous SO thread in which various unicode matching mechanisms are discussed.