# Validate input with NodeJS to accept alphanum for all languages

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to validate input with NodeJS but I'm facing a lot of language problems. When I'm using validator.js, then I need to select a specific language and can't choose all. And when I'm using other alphanum validators, then they don't accept Japanese and other non-latin based alphabets.
Anyone with good ideas or experience of this that can help?

Comment: You can check [JavaScript regex for validating for alphanumeric characters,all international characters (Japanese, Chinese, Russian etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006998/javascript-regex-for-validating-for-alphanumeric-characters-all-international-ch).

Comment: I don't like it but it's the best solution I can find. Thank you for the help :)