# how to validate text for only , English characters and , Non English characters jquery validater

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate a text box to ensure only characters and Unicode characters can be added to it. For example, the following would be valid:

```
Gräfelfing
Gießen
München
```

But these should be invalid:

```
Gräfelfing123
Gießen!@#$
München123#@#
```

I know how to validate for characters using validator method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z]+$/i.test(jQuery.trim(value));
    }, "Letters only please");
```

But how can I add Unicode character validation to this? Please help, thanks in advance.

---

*** UPDATE ***

I tried a solution with the help of this question - [Regular expression to match non-English characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters).

But it is not working:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z\u0000-\u0080]+$/i.test(jQuery.trim(value));
    }, "Letters only please");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match non-english characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript lacks built-in character classe for "all latin-based letters with diactrics", so you must decide yourself what you really want to accept.

For example:

- do you want to accept Cyrillic (Russian, Bulgarian, Belorussian, etc)?
- Do you want to support kana (Japanese) or hangul (Korean)?

Those all are "non-Englih (or, more correctly: non-Latin) letters" after all.

After you've decided:

- consult [code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) and just list all the ranges you want in your regexp
- You can use [this tool](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block) to create a regex filtered by Unicode block.

**Example**

To add diactrics to list of allowed chars in the check in your code, you can use `/^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]+$/i`
That will cover

- Latin-1 Supplement
- Latin Extended-A
- Latin Extended-B ranges.

This should cover most of used diactrics and works will all examples you've provided.
Mix and match as you want.