# Python regex uppercase unicode word

Tags: python, regex

I need to find abbreviations text in many languages. Current [regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) is:

```
import regex as re
pattern = re.compile('(?:[\w]\.)+', re.UNICODE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL | re.VERSION1)
pattern.findall("U.S.A. u.s.a.")
```

I don't need **u.s.a** in the result, i need only uppercase text. **[A-Z]** won't work in any language except english.

Comment: You may find some help at this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters

Comment: there is javascript. i'm using python

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use a Unicode character property in order to match them. `re` does not support character properties, but [`regex`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) does.

```
>>> regex.findall(ur'\p{Lu}', u'ÜìÑ')
[u'\xdc', u'\xd1']
```

Comment: The `Lu` in `\p{Lu}` marks the character properties **L**etter **u**ppercase.

Wikipedia has [more information and examples on character properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category).

The [regex documentation](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/README.rst#rst-header-unicode-codepoint-properties-including-scripts-and-blocks) indicates that some of the other exampls are also supported.