# Loop through a string with variable and replace an uppercase it with # in Python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, uppercase, iterable

I want to loop through a string and when it finds an uppercase letter, I want to replace it with #. Like this:

```
string = "hOw Are yOu?"
for x in string:
  if x.isupper():
    string.replace(x, "#")
    print(string)
  else:
    print(string)
```

However, its not working as intended and is instead outputting the same string. Do tell me if there is a way to fix this or if you'd suggest another way.

Comment: Strings are not mutable in Python.  `string.replace(...)` returns a *new* string with the replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Python. `string.replace(x, "#")` must thus be `string = string.replace(x, "#")` to have an effect on the string.

Note that currently your code has quadratic complexity as each replace operation has to loop over the entire string in linear time. A more efficient approach would be to perform the replacements yourself, as you're already looping over every character:

```py
string = "".join(["#" if c.isupper() else c for c in "hOw Are yOu?"])
```

it would be even more concise (and possibly faster) to use a *very simple* RegEx for this:

```
import re
string = re.sub("[A-Z]", "#", "hOw Are yOu?")
```

this will fail for non-ASCII alphabets however; you'd have to use [unicode properties & `regex` there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593509/python-regex-uppercase-unicode-word).

Comment: Can you suggest a better way to do it? The current code is repeating the same amount  of times as the characters of the string. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @JeromJaison yes, that's exactly what I mean. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Can you show a better way to do it? This code is not working the way I wanted it to.

Comment: @JeromJaison "This code is not working the way I wanted it to" - please elaborate.

Comment: Nvm, it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with join:

```
In [4]: ''.join([i if not i.isupper() else '#' for i in string])
Out[4]: 'h#w #re y#u?'
```

Answer (score 1):

You just want to put the result again in string see below

```
string = "hOw Are yOu?"
for x in string:
    if x.isupper():
        string = string.replace(x, "#")
        print(string)
    else:
        print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick!

```
string = "hOw Are yOu?"
for x in string:
  if x.isupper():
    string = string.replace(x, "#")
  else:
    pass
print(string)
```

I'm a novice as well! But from what I learned: when doing loops or if statements, you want to specify the value you are changing as I did in line 4 with: string = string.replace(x,'#') If not the change will not take effect!

```
Example:
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
for x in my_list:
    my_list[x-1] = x + 1
print(my_list)
```

This is a poor example coding wise but it exemplifies the concept. If you don't address the variable it wont have any effect on it!

Hope this helps!