# Regex for allowing alphanumeric,-,_ and space

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am searching for a regular expression for allowing alphanumeric characters, -, _ or spaces in JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: Try `/[a-z\d\-_\s]+/i`. But you may want to _learn_ regex. You can't find them all on the web, specially if it's not common.

Comment: yes i am very weak at it

Comment: @elclanrs not working for me

Comment: Yeah forgot the start and end chars: `/^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i`. That's why regex are useful to know... I learned here http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: @elclanrs yes it's working please post your solution as answer so i can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i
```

Comment: @rahul: This works but check Nevir's answer because it should work too and it's a bit shorter. Basically `\w` means alpha + underscore, it's just a shortcut like `\d` means `[0-9]`.

Comment: Try this Regex `/^[\w]+([-_\s]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*$/i` This will allow only single space or - or _ between text `Ex: atoz-some word_1234`

Answer (score 110):

[Character sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) will help out a ton here.  You want to create a matching set for the characters that you want to validate:

- You can match alphanumeric with a `\w`, which is the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]` in JavaScript (other languages can differ).
- That leaves `-` and spaces, which can be combined into a matching set such as `[\w\- ]`.  However, you may want to consider using `\s` instead of just the space character (`\s` also matches tabs, and other forms of whitespace)

  - *Note that I'm escaping `-` as `\-` so that the regex engine doesn't confuse it with a character range like `A-Z`*
- Last up, you probably want to ensure that the entire string matches [by anchoring](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the start and end via `^` and `$`

The full regex you're probably looking for is:

```
/^[\w\-\s]+$/
```

(Note that [the `+` indicates](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) that there must be *at least* one character for it to match; use a `*` instead, if a zero-length string is also ok)

Finally, http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is an awesome reference

**Bonus Points:**  This regex *does not* match non-ASCII alphas.  Unfortunately, the regex engine in most browsers does not support named character sets, [but there are some libraries to help with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters).

For languages/platforms that do support named character sets, you can use `/^[\p{Letter}\d\_\-\s]+$/`

Comment: This is better than my answer, since `[a-z[0-9]_]/i` is the same as `\w`

Comment: This doesnt work when we provide space as first char

Comment: why are there beginning and ending slashes? this worked for me (in PostgreSQL)  when i remove d the start and end  `/`

Answer (score 12):

```
/^[-\w\s]+$/
```

**\w** matches *letters*, *digits*, and *underscores*

**\s** matches *spaces*, *tabs*, and *line breaks*

**-**  matches the *hyphen* (if you have hyphen in your character set example [a-z], be sure to place the hyphen at the beginning like so [-a-z])

Answer (score 10):

```
var string = 'test- _ 0Test';
string.match(/^[-_ a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9? ,_-]+$");
            var key = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
```

in the regExp `[A-Za-z0-9?spaceHere,_-]` there is a literal space after the question mark '?'.  This matches space. Others like `/^[-\w\s]+$/` and `/^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i` were not working for me.

Comment: This allows basics special characters that needed " ",?,:, .... And blocking others. THanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this regex

*Updated regex

```
/^[a-z0-9]+([-_\s]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*$/i
```

This will allow only single space or - or _ between the text

```
Ex: this-some abc123_regex
```

To learn : https://regexr.com

*Note: I have updated the regex based on Toto question

Comment: Why do you want to match single space hyphen or underscore? This is not what it was aked. And your regex [matches `_______`](https://regex101.com/r/BO0cER/1)

Comment: I have reason for that.
Assume that there is a field for username with @elclanrs regex (first answer). In this case an real time user can simply enter `---_ _ _` this in his username field and validation become passed which is toally wrong.
So to avoid that i have given regex like that with conditions.

Comment: But your regex matches `____` which is wrong, see the link provided in my previous comment.

Comment: It allways match `_____ ` (a space at the end).

Comment: Now no special characters allowed except 'hyphen' and 'underscore'

Answer (score 0):

For me I wanted a regex which supports a strings as preceding. Basically, the motive is to support some foreign countries postal format as it should be an alphanumeric with spaces allowed.

1. ABC123
2. ABC 123
3. ABC123(space)
4. ABC 123 (space)

So I ended up by writing custom regex as below.

```
/^([a-z]+[\s]*[0-9]+[\s]*)+$/i
```

[image]

Here, I gave * in `[\s]*` as it is not mandatory to have a space. A postal code may or may not contains space in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
var1 regex = new     RegExp1("^[A-Za-z0-9? ,_-]+$");
var1 key = String1.fromCharCode(event1.charCode ? event1.which : event1.charCode);

if (!regex1.test(key)) {
  event1.preventDefault();
  return false;   
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This answer was flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality), and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32203832)

Answer (score -1):

Following both are worked for me.

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_\s]/g
/[^a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i
```

Can replace other except alphanumerics, -, _ with empty like this.

```
inputString.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_\s]/g,"");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this for allowing alphanumeric and space

[a-zA-Z0-9 ]