# Regular expression not matching words with space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex: `/\*\*[A-z0-9]+\*\*/g` It's supposed to match words with double * around them, like so: `**this whole sentence should match**`

However it's not matching the spaces. So `**this is a word**` (this would not be matched), however `**word**` would be matched (without spaces).

Should match:

- `**this sentence is bold**`
- `**this should also match**`
- `**should**`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283470/regex-for-allowing-alphanumeric-and-space. BTW, `A-z` defines a range that also includes some chars other than just ASCII letters. Use `/\*\*[a-z0-9\s]+\*\*/gi`

Comment: Perfect @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1):

The expression you wrote will find a match when the subject starts with two *s (star-star) characters and any character in your caracter set [A-z0-9] (any ASCII character from A to Z or a - z or any digit like 1234567890) and ends with two *s (star start) characters. What is missing here is including a space in your character set. By including "\ " you are specifying that a space litteral is also a valid character in your expression.

```
\*\*[A-z0-9\ ]+\*\*
```

Please note that this will match on any number of spaces so words like `**john   doe   **` will still be considered valid.
If you only want to match on one space you can consider:

```
\*\*(?:[A-z0-9](?:[\ ]?))+\*\*
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a space in character class will solve the problem.

```
/\*\*[A-z0-9 ]+\*\*/g
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Wiktor Stribizew does also include tabs and new lines. If you would like to only include spaces a solution as

```
/\*\*[a-z0-9 ]+\*\*/gi
```

will do. The `\s` is replaced with a single space. Since the plus sign `+` is added, multiple spaces will alse be matched.