# change wp results page depending on its url

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I hope you can help me to figure this out. I need to be able to build a regular expression in js that allows letters, numbers and symbols such as plus (+) just after the ?s=...

right now I'm trying something like this

```
var regexp = '^[a-z0-9]';
if (url == 'https://digitalswitch.cl/rileditores/?s=' + regexp){
   //do something
}else{
   //do something else
}
```

Comment: see [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and fix your regex, it's not valid as it stand right now.

Comment: symbols ,,,you should list how many symbols you could accept

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for allowing alphanumeric,-,\_ and space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283470/regex-for-allowing-alphanumeric-and-space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var str     = "https://digitalswitch.cl/rileditores/?s=sample";
var matches = str.match(/\?s=([^&]*)/);
if(matches){
   alert('matched');
}else{
   alert('not matched');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The following example will search "?s" is available at the link or not. If yes alert "matched", else "not matched".

Hope this will helps you.

For more example,

- [Capture value out of query string with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126956/capture-value-out-of-query-string-with-regex)