# Regex who allows aphanumeric and space. Using UTF8

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex who allows aphanumeric and space. UTF8

Example:

é, á, a, A, 1 and space.

What the problem of anothers aswers like that: [Regex for allowing alphanumeric,-,_ and space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283470/regex-for-allowing-alphanumeric-and-space)

Because it does not work using UTF8 like ( Á, ô).

Comment: It depends on the implementation, not on regex itself. DotNet regexp for example, is quite happy with utf-8, as its internal char representation is unicode friendly. So please tag your question with the environment you are working in.

Comment: Using javascript with reactjs framework

Comment: Make sure to use the [unicode flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicode) when building your regex. (i.e. `/.../u`).

Answer (score 2):

it seems to already work...

```js
var regex = /é/;
console.log(regex.test('é'));//true
```

Comment: Dont understand. console.log(regex.test('í')) returns false

Comment: is `regex=/í/` ?

Comment: So, about a phrase like that: "Frete transportadora x em até 20 dias úteis" ? i need something who accept that and gives error when set special characters, for example like: =-,;*&(!@

Comment: do you want to blacklist all the unwanted characters, or you prefer to set a list of permitted characters?

Answer (score 1):

To match `[\p{L}\p{Nd} ]` in JavaScript you can use:

```
[\u0020\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00AA\u00B5\u00BA\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376-\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u052F\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0620-\u064A\u0660-\u0669\u066E-\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5-\u06E6\u06EE-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07C0-\u07EA\u07F4-\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u0815\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08A0-\u08B4\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0966-\u096F\u0971-\u0980\u0985-\u098C\u098F-\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC-\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09E6-\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F-\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32-\u0A33\u0A35-\u0A36\u0A38-\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A66-\u0A6F\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2-\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0-\u0AE1\u0AE6-\u0AEF\u0AF9\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F-\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32-\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C-\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B66-\u0B6F\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99-\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E-\u0B9F\u0BA3-\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0BE6-\u0BEF\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58-\u0C5A\u0C60-\u0C61\u0C66-\u0C6F\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0-\u0CE1\u0CE6-\u0CEF\u0CF1-\u0CF2\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D5F-\u0D61\u0D66-\u0D6F\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0DE6-\u0DEF\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32-\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E50-\u0E59\u0E81-\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87-\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA-\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2-\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0ED0-\u0ED9\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F20-\u0F29\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F-\u1049\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065-\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u1090-\u1099\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F5\u13F8-\u13FD\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16F1-\u16F8\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u17E0-\u17E9\u1810-\u1819\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1946-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19B0-\u19C9\u19D0-\u19D9\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1A80-\u1A89\u1A90-\u1A99\u1AA7\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B50-\u1B59\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C40-\u1C49\u1C4D-\u1C7D\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF1\u1CF5-\u1CF6\u1D00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2183-\u2184\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CEE\u2CF2-\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2E2F\u3005-\u3006\u3031-\u3035\u303B-\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FD5\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA62B\uA640-\uA66E\uA67F-\uA69D\uA6A0-\uA6E5\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA7AD\uA7B0-\uA7B7\uA7F7-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8D0-\uA8D9\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA8FD\uA900-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uA9CF-\uA9D9\uA9E0-\uA9E4\uA9E6-\uA9FE\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA50-\uAA59\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA7E-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5-\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEA\uAAF2-\uAAF4\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB65\uAB70-\uABE2\uABF0-\uABF9\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40-\uFB41\uFB43-\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF10-\uFF19\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]
```