# Regular Expression fails for foreign alphabets

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex `"/^[a-zA-Z]{2,50}$/"` which i use for an input field. This works perfectly for the English alphabet. But this doesn't work for Foreign alphabets. When I enter any foreign language, for example, **Ağustos**, the regex fails. How can I solve this?

I use **preg_match** for testing.

Comment: `\p{L}{2,50}` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855335/validate-field-for-all-language-characters-through-regex

Comment: @CodeManiac Can you explain ? Not returning match

Comment: @melvin for reference you can check this https://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html

Comment: Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/150078/2406912 . In short you need to match unicode characters or non-ascii character.

Comment: You need the unicode flag `u`: `preg_match_all('/^\p{L}+$/u', 'Ağustos', $m);`

Answer (score 0):

The regex to matche any kind of letter from any language is `\p{L}` so in your case the regex would be `\p{L}{2,50}`

You can test this on regex101 to see it work

Comment: I have tested this and is not returning match group

Comment: @melvin then you are probably implementing it incorrectly, you can test it on regex101.com for php and it marks `Ağustos` as a match. I would share a link but regex101 seems to be unable to generate any shareable links right now

Comment: Are you sure? regex101.com is not available now. I tested on other sites and was not getting any result

Comment: @melvin yes I tested it as i was posting the answer, it is loading a lot slower than normal and not generating shareable links but it is working

Comment: @melvin look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135114/what-does-the-regex-pattern-pl-do) for more info, explains the use of \\pL a lot better, also I do hope you did remember to escape all the needed characters

Comment: This regex matches only one letter

Comment: @melvin did you add the `{2,50}` after it ?

Comment: Yes. I have added. I have tested this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208534/discussion-between-karan-shishoo-and-melvin).