# How to validate a string contains only latin characters including diacritics

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a MVC application that will be used internationally.

I want to have text inputs that validate if the text entered contains only latin characters, including diacritics, but no other characters that come from other languages (like cyrillic, japanese, chinese, arabic characters)

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Valid examples:

- Hello
- Añejo
- Exposición
- l'italiano

Invalid examples:

- シアトル
- вода
- 曝光

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15379517/961113

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!