# How do I handle non-English characters properly?

Tags: java, string, unicode, character-encoding, char

So I'm working with last.fm API. Sometimes, the query results in tracks that contain characters like these:

`Æther`, `é`, `Hṛṣṭa`

or non-English characters like these:

`水鏡`.

When debugging in Eclipse, I see them just fine (as-is) but printing on console prints these as `???` - which is OK for me.

Now, how do I handle these? At first I though I could remove every song that has any character other than the ones in English language. I used the regex `^\\w+$` but it didn't work. I also tried `\\w+`. That didn't work either.

Then I thought further on how do handle these properly. Any one can help me out? I am perfectly fine with letting these tracks out of the equation, ie. I'm fine with having only English character tracks.

Another question: What is the best way to display these character of console and/or Swing GUI?

Comment: The problem is likely that the console does not support UTF-8 or the font it is using doesn't have glyphs for them.

Comment: Do you mean the Eclipse output console, or an actual operating system command line console? If command line, which operating system and console are you using?

Comment: Ah, so I changed the encoding to UTF-8. Perfect. So now, how can I check whether a string contains such characters?

Comment: @Arkanon I meant Eclipse console.

Comment: is this what you want [Regular expression to match non-english characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)

Comment: @BevynQ Perfect! Work. But could you explain what the `x80` means? The last hex code should be `7F` right?

Comment: I agree the range should be `0x00-0x7F`

Comment: Why do you need to check? Just use UTF-8 always.

Comment: "At first I though I could remove every song that has any character other than the ones in English language." WHYYYYYYYYYYYY

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky But I'm just concerned what if some users do not have support for UTF-8 and the text messes up?

Comment: We are in the year 2013 - everybody should sufficiently support UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that you use correct encoding when reading your input first.

Second ensure that the font used in Eclipse on platform you developing has ability to display all these characters. Swing must display unicode chars if you read them correctly.

You will likely want to use UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: So if I have the correct encoding on my development platform, is it guaranteed that the program will work fine on other platforms as well?

Comment: If you give your correct app to another user he will need to use correct font as well on his platform in console. E.g. on Linux some default fonts could be not Unicode.

Comment: so basically there are three issues with encoding: 1. how you read your input. 2. how you write output and 3. fonts which display output :-)