# include all foreign characters in regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I have the following if statement with a regular expression to check if an entry does not have lowercase and uppercase letters, however I need to include all foreign characters too like ü, ó etc. How could I include all these in my regex?

```
if (regsurname.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g)) {
....
```

The main idea of it is to stop people from entering numbers or characters like *-/ in the surname field.

**EDIT:** I read that it can be done with this `\p{L}` but how would I include that in my regex exactly?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want to include them [all](http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.3.0/ucd/UnicodeData-6.3.0d2.txt) ?

Comment: yes all letters and all foreign letters

Comment: There are several thousands of them, you know. And unicode regexes like `\p{L}` don't work in javascript.

Comment: Take 5 steps back. What are you trying to validate here to begin with and why? You want to validate *human names from any culture?* Then the best thing is not to.

Comment: I want people not to be able to write numbers or symbols like */-; etc.

Comment: In many cultures `-` is a valid character to indicate multiple last names. Similarly, `'` comes to mind for the Irish `O'-` last names. And that's only scratching the surface of possibilities. I'd also recommend not limiting the length of the field, or setting it to long enough - for example, for the multiple Spanish last names.

Comment: John Doe the 3rd won't be able to register then? Neither will Mrs. Schmidt-Schultz?

Answer (score 0):

[Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29) regexp sequences like `p{L}` are [supported in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) but not [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) as far as I know.

- [Javascript + Unicode regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode)
- [Regular expression to match non-English characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)

Many surnames are hyphenated. It seems like you'd want to allow `-`.

Comment: nm i believe it is according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#pattern)