# \d only matchs 0-9 digits?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, internationalization

As far as I know, `\d` should matchs non-english digits, e.g. `۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰` but it doesn't work properly in JavaScript.

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xZpam/

Is this a normal behavior?

Comment: It is normal. The question is whether you can enable the unicode behavior in javascript regexes. Chrome doesn't like the `u` flag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters

Comment: Since it only matches [0-9] why not try something like `^[۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰]+$`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript does not support Unicode regex matching (and it is far from the only language where such is true).

http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: Adding to what Amber said, `JavaScript uses ASCII for \d and \w, but Unicode for \s`. [Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: yes, and now it's a trouble having good client validation with JS regexps

Comment: Languages that properly support Unicode regex matching tend to be the exception, actually.

Answer (score 11):

It seems that JavaScript does not support this (along with other weaknesses of the language in RegExp). However there's a library called [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) that has a unicode addon, which enables unicode support through `\p{}` category definition. For example if you use `\p{Nd}` instead of `\d` it will match digits:

```
<script src="xregexp-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var englishDigits = '123123';
    var nonEnglishDigits = '۱۲۳۱۲۳';

    var digitsPattern = XRegExp('\\p{Nd}+');
    if (digitsPattern.test(nonEnglishDigits)) {
        alert('Non-english using xregexp');
    }

    if (digitsPattern.test(englishDigits)) {
        alert('English using xregexp');
    }
</script>
```

---

#### EDIT:

Used `\p{Nd}` instead of `\p{N}` as it seems that `\d` is equivalent to `\p{Nd}` in non ECMA Script Regex engines. Thanks go to [Shervin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016778/shervin) for pointing it out. See also this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wZXZ3/2/) by [Shervin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016778/shervin).

Comment: And if you want to limit your input to [Arabic-Indic](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7Bsubhead%3DArabic-Indic+digits%7D&g=) or [Eastern Arabic-Indic Digits](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=\p{subhead=Eastern%20Arabic-Indic%20digits}) you can use Unicode block criteria:

`alert(XRegExp("^\\p{InArabic}\\p{N}").test('۱۲۳۴٤۵٥۶۷۸۹۰')); // True`
`alert(XRegExp("^\\p{InArabic}\\p{N}").test('1234567890')); // False`

Comment: @Sina, I think that `\\p{N}` (Number) should be replaced with `\\p{Nd}` (Decimal Number) since we don't want to match [non-decimal numeral characters](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7BN%7D-%5Cp%7BNd%7D&g=) like ➋, ⅑, Ⅷ, etc.: http://jsfiddle.net/wZXZ3/2/

Comment: @Shervin Thanks, I updated the answer, and linked to your fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

In the documention of Mozilla Firefox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) you will find that:

```
\d  

Matches a digit character in the basic Latin alphabet. Equivalent to [0-9].
```

Answer (score 2):

`\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-digit).

Answer (score 1):

From MDN . [RegEx Test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

> Matches a digit character in the basic Latin alphabet. Equivalent to
>   [0-9].

Answer (score 1):

```
Matches a digit character. Equivalent to [0-9].

For example, /\d/ or /[0-9]/ matches '2' in "B2 is the suite number."
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-digit)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal and correct that `\d` matches the Ascii digits `0` to `9` only. The authoritative reference is the [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). It is not particularly easy reading, but clause 15.10.2.12 (CharacterClassEscape) specifies that `\d` denotes “the ten-element set of characters containing the characters 0 through 9 inclusive”.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes,** using `\d` not matching properly to  **none-English numbers** in JavaScript, But like other weird parts of JavaScript, you can still check **none-English numbers** (like **Persian** numbers for example) in JavaScript, using something like the code below:

```
/[۰, ۹]/.test("۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰"); //true
```