# Regex Expression allowing special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using an online regex checker such as [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to check my regex which is to be used by javascript such as (*working but cut down* regex for example only)

```
state = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/.test($(control).val())
```

My Regex is

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9].{5,19}
```

Which when cut down into chunks should hopefully mean...

```
(?=.*[A-Z])  - Must include an Upper case char
(?=.*[0-9])  - Must include a numeric 
[a-zA-Z0-9. ]  - Can include any lower  or upper case char, or Numeric, a period or space
.            - Matching previous
{5,19}       - the string must be 6-20 characters in length
```

This however still allows special characters such as !.

I've not used \d for decimals as I believe [0-9] should be more strict in this regard, and removed the period and space to see whether this was the cause, to no avail.

Where have I gone wrong to be allowing special characters?

Comment: Remove the `.` in the 'Matching' previous line, the `.` matches any single character except new line, which is matching the `!` - try this - `(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,19}`. also \d is exactly the same as [0-9]

Comment: `.` matches any character, not "previous". If you're actually using regex101.com: https://regex101.com/r/BUMWzO/1, it will tell you that: ".{5,19} matches any character (except for line terminators)"

Comment: Cheers chaps for the quick replies. @MarkWalters as you were just first please free to post the answer for the points. Thanks again. Not sure where I got that dot idea from!

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - I hadn't even spotted that. I guess there's "using it" and "using it properly". Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the last `.` which you think is matching previous, it actually matches any character except for newline, so this is where the ! is getting through.

So `(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9].{5,19}` should be `(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,19}`

Also just thought i'd mention there is no difference between `\d` and `[0-9]` whatsoever.

**UPDATED -** this following should fix the issues you were seeing with the regex - `(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9\.\s]{6,20}$`

- Added `\.` (to allow a .)
- Added `\s` (to allow whitespace characters)
- Changed `{5, 19}` to `{6, 20}$` to ensure the correct character match

If you want to test this version of the regex in regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/4jQFnp/1)

Comment: There is, actually, a difference between `\d` and `[0-9]`!. `\d` is slower, since it also takes into account numbers in other languages. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/1197418) is a good explanation.

Comment: @juanlu Actually just read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662946/d-only-matchs-0-9-digits. Unicode regex matching is not supported in JavaScript so \d is equivalent to [0-9] in JS.

Comment: Interestingly, after testing more, your answer it only seems to check the first 5 characters. A1CDE matches, but so does A1CDE!, although A1C!DE fails as it's only matching the first 5..

Comment: @MarkWalters you are absolutely right, JS does not seem to support it. Good to know!

Comment: Is there any way you could actually enter the link description there?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I've just seen what you mean, that's an error on my part, the link is mentioned at the bottom.

Comment: I was talking about the stuff you just edited out -- "enter link description here" at the beginning. Default link text bothers me for some reason; I also can't look at designs with "Lorem ipsum" too long ;).