# How to add a span tag to wrap the other string not in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to  add a span tag to wrap the other string not in regex?

```
// This is english & some <span>中文</span> character <span>字元</span>.

var str = 'This is english & some 中文 character 字元.'

var pattern = new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z0-9 _^!-~-]/);
console.log( pattern.test(str));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "This is english & some 中文 character 字元.";
var regex = /([^a-zA-Z0-9 _^!-~-]+)/g;
console.log(str.replace(regex, '<span>$1</span>'));
// This is english & some <span>中文</span> character <span>字元</span>.
```

I have used your regex with the following changes:

- Added capturing group by adding `()` so that matches can be *captured*
- Then use the captured group in replacement using `$1`
- Added a `g` flag for global which means all matches must be replaced instead of just the first one.

You might be interested in the regular expressions discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/150033/87015).

Comment: Thanks so much! have few question what is `$1` and why you add a `g` in regex?

Comment: is there any different use regex like mine and unicode  any suggestion or just the same thing

Comment: The other question says "Regular expression to match non-english characters" so I thought may be this is what you want :)