# RegEx to test if a string contains more than X Unicode words

Tags: javascript, regex

I saw many solutions that match Latin characters words like this one: `/^\W*(\w+\b\W*){80,}$/`
I'm looking for the equivalent expression that will support any language with Unicode characters.

The RegEx need to be JavaScript compatible.

Comment: Maybe this would help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Javascript sadly doesn't seem to support this solution... You might want to look into [XRegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xregexp.html)

I'll leave this here in case it's of use for anyone in another language more Perl compatible, but this doesn't answer your question, sorry.

---

For unicode support you can use the `\p{...}` [pattern](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Your pattern would become

```
/^\P{L}*(\p{L}+\P{L}*){80,}$/
```

Here `\P{L}` stands for anything but a letter, `\p{L}` for any letter (but not a digit or a `_`, so it's a little bit different from `\w`)