# regex ALLOW foreign characters while filtering out special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I saw this post: [Regular expression to match non-English characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters) which allows you to  filter out foreign characters like so
`str = str.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]+/g, "");`

I am trying to **allow** these characters while filtering out special charaters  but allowing `'- _` << single quote, hyphen, underscore and empty space

question: how can i combine the 2 to allow foreign characters in this javascript regex? 
`str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9'-_ ]/g, "");`

lets say i want the `ü`, this **does not** work `str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9'-_ ü]/g, "");`

Comment: [You want to allow `-_ `](https://www.debuggex.com/i/i18JXYOQ8rOvNZA1.png). Use: `[^A-z0-9'".]` and all the other symbols you can possibly have from `\x00` to `\x7F`

Comment: thank you but how does this translate to javascript? i have been unsuccessful with the code

Comment: are you trying to allow a dash and underscore?

Comment: So you want to allow letters from foreign alphabets, but what about non-ascii special characters?  For example ♥★☐↑

Comment: @F.J correct, i would like to filter out dingbat and other graphic symbols.  only allow alpha numeric + foreign char + hyphen, underscore, single quote, empty space

Comment: The following resources may be useful: http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_cset, https://github.com/paulmillr/unicode-categories.  I haven't used either but I don't know if you'll do any better than some crazy long regex that implements the Unicode character ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is pretty complex because no matter how you slice it you either have a ton of Unicode letters to include or a ton of Unicode special characters to exclude.  What you essentially need here is a regex that will only allow characters from the [Unicode general categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) for letters (Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo).

In some regex flavors support for Unicode general categories is built in, and your regex would just be something like the following:

```
[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}'\- _]
```

Unfortunately JavaScript does not support this, but you could do this with the [Unicode addon to the XRegExp library](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode), the usage would look something like this (for filtering out all of the characters you do not want):

```
XRegExp.replace(text, "[^\\p{Ll}\\p{Lu}\\p{Lt}\\p{Lm}\\p{Lo}'\\- _]", '', 'all');
```

Or alternatively if you want to construct a crazy long JavaScript regex that does the job, the [CSET JavaScript library](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_cset) can be used, here is the regex I came up with:

```
var regex = /[\u0000-\u001f!-&(-,.-@[-^`{-©«-´¶-¹»-¿×÷˂-˅˒-˟˥-˫˭˯-\u036f͵\u0378-\u0379;-΅·\u038b\u038d\u03a2϶҂-\u0489\u0524-\u0530\u0557-\u0558՚-\u0560\u0588-\u05cf\u05eb-\u05ef׳-\u0620\u064b-٭\u0670۔\u06d6-\u06e4\u06e7-\u06ed۰-۹۽-۾܀-\u070f\u0711\u0730-\u074c\u07a6-\u07b0\u07b2-߉\u07eb-\u07f3߶-߹\u07fb-\u0903\u093a-\u093c\u093e-\u094f\u0951-\u0957\u0962-॰\u0973-\u097a\u0980-\u0984\u098d-\u098e\u0991-\u0992\u09a9\u09b1\u09b3-\u09b5\u09ba-\u09bc\u09be-\u09cd\u09cf-\u09db\u09de\u09e2-৯৲-\u0a04\u0a0b-\u0a0e\u0a11-\u0a12\u0a29\u0a31\u0a34\u0a37\u0a3a-\u0a58\u0a5d\u0a5f-\u0a71\u0a75-\u0a84\u0a8e\u0a92\u0aa9\u0ab1\u0ab4\u0aba-\u0abc\u0abe-\u0acf\u0ad1-\u0adf\u0ae2-\u0b04\u0b0d-\u0b0e\u0b11-\u0b12\u0b29\u0b31\u0b34\u0b3a-\u0b3c\u0b3e-\u0b5b\u0b5e\u0b62-୰\u0b72-\u0b82\u0b84\u0b8b-\u0b8d\u0b91\u0b96-\u0b98\u0b9b\u0b9d\u0ba0-\u0ba2\u0ba5-\u0ba7\u0bab-\u0bad\u0bba-\u0bcf\u0bd1-\u0c04\u0c0d\u0c11\u0c29\u0c34\u0c3a-\u0c3c\u0c3e-\u0c57\u0c5a-\u0c5f\u0c62-\u0c84\u0c8d\u0c91\u0ca9\u0cb4\u0cba-\u0cbc\u0cbe-\u0cdd\u0cdf\u0ce2-\u0d04\u0d0d\u0d11\u0d29\u0d3a-\u0d3c\u0d3e-\u0d5f\u0d62-൹\u0d80-\u0d84\u0d97-\u0d99\u0db2\u0dbc\u0dbe-\u0dbf\u0dc7-\u0e00\u0e31\u0e34-฿\u0e47-\u0e80\u0e83\u0e85-\u0e86\u0e89\u0e8b-\u0e8c\u0e8e-\u0e93\u0e98\u0ea0\u0ea4\u0ea6\u0ea8-\u0ea9\u0eac\u0eb1\u0eb4-\u0ebc\u0ebe-\u0ebf\u0ec5\u0ec7-\u0edb\u0ede-\u0eff༁-\u0f3f\u0f48\u0f6d-\u0f87\u0f8c-\u0fff\u102b-\u103e၀-၏\u1056-\u1059\u105e-\u1060\u1062-\u1064\u1067-\u106d\u1071-\u1074\u1082-\u108d\u108f-႟\u10c6-\u10cf჻\u10fd-\u10ff\u115a-\u115e\u11a3-\u11a7\u11fa-\u11ff\u1249\u124e-\u124f\u1257\u1259\u125e-\u125f\u1289\u128e-\u128f\u12b1\u12b6-\u12b7\u12bf\u12c1\u12c6-\u12c7\u12d7\u1311\u1316-\u1317\u135b-\u137f᎐-\u139f\u13f5-\u1400᙭-᙮\u1677-\u1680᚛-\u169f᛫-\u16ff\u170d\u1712-\u171f\u1732-\u173f\u1752-\u175f\u176d\u1771-\u177f\u17b4-៖៘-៛\u17dd-\u181f\u1878-\u187f\u18a9\u18ab-\u18ff\u191d-᥏\u196e-\u196f\u1975-\u197f\u19aa-\u19c0\u19c8-᧿\u1a17-\u1b04\u1b34-\u1b44\u1b4c-\u1b82\u1ba1-\u1bad᮰-\u1bff\u1c24-\u1c4c᱐-᱙᱾-\u1cff\u1dc0-\u1dff\u1f16-\u1f17\u1f1e-\u1f1f\u1f46-\u1f47\u1f4e-\u1f4f\u1f58\u1f5a\u1f5c\u1f5e\u1f7e-\u1f7f\u1fb5᾽᾿-῁\u1fc5῍-῏\u1fd4-\u1fd5\u1fdc-῟῭-\u1ff1\u1ff5´-⁰\u2072-⁾₀-\u208f\u2095-℁℃-℆℈-℉℔№-℘℞-℣℥℧℩℮℺-℻⅀-⅄⅊-⅍⅏-\u2182\u2185-\u2bff\u2c2f\u2c5f\u2c70\u2c7e-\u2c7f⳥-⳿\u2d26-\u2d2f\u2d66-\u2d6e\u2d70-\u2d7f\u2d97-\u2d9f\u2da7\u2daf\u2db7\u2dbf\u2dc7\u2dcf\u2dd7\u2ddf-⸮⸰-〄\u3007-〰〶-\u303a〽-\u3040\u3097-゜゠・\u3100-\u3104\u312e-\u3130\u318f-㆟\u31b8-\u31ef㈀-㏿\u4db6-䷿\u9fc4-\u9fff\ua48d-\ua4ff꘍-꘏꘠-꘩\ua62c-\ua63f\ua660-\ua661\ua66f-꙾\ua698-꜖꜠-꜡꞉-꞊\ua78d-\ua7fa\ua802\ua806\ua80b\ua823-\ua83f꡴-\ua881\ua8b4-꤉\ua926-꤯\ua947-\ua9ff\uaa29-\uaa3f\uaa43\uaa4c-\uabff\ud7a4-\ud7ff\ud840-\ud868\udc00-\uf8ff\ufa2e-\ufa2f\ufa6b-\ufa6f\ufada-\ufaff\ufb07-\ufb12\ufb18-\ufb1c\ufb1e﬩\ufb37\ufb3d\ufb3f\ufb42\ufb45\ufbb2-\ufbd2﴾-\ufd4f\ufd90-\ufd91\ufdc8-\ufdef﷼-\ufe6f\ufe75\ufefd-＠［-｀｛-･\uffbf-\uffc1\uffc8-\uffc9\uffd0-\uffd1\uffd8-\uffd9\uffdd-\uffff]|[\ud803-\ud807\ud809-\ud834\ud836-\ud83f\ud86a-\ud87d\ud87f-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|\ud800[\udc0c\udc27\udc3b\udc3e\udc4e-\udc4f\udc5e-\udc7f\udcfb-\ude7f\ude9d-\ude9f\uded1-\udeff\udf1f-\udf2f\udf41\udf4a-\udf7f\udf9e-\udf9f\udfc4-\udfc7\udfd0-\udfff]|\ud801[\udc9e-\udfff]|\ud802[\udc06-\udc07\udc09\udc36\udc39-\udc3b\udc3d-\udc3e\udc40-\udcff\udd16-\udd1f\udd3a-\uddff\ude01-\ude0f\ude14\ude18\ude34-\udfff]|\ud808[\udf6f-\udfff]|\ud835[\udc55\udc9d\udca0-\udca1\udca3-\udca4\udca7-\udca8\udcad\udcba\udcbc\udcc4\udd06\udd0b-\udd0c\udd15\udd1d\udd3a\udd3f\udd45\udd47-\udd49\udd51\udea6-\udea7\udec1\udedb\udefb\udf15\udf35\udf4f\udf6f\udf89\udfa9\udfc3\udfcc-\udfff]|\ud869[\uded7-\udfff]|\ud87e[\ude1e-\udfff]|[\ud800-\ud83f\ud869-\udbff]/g;
```

And the steps to get there (after including the CSET source):

```
CSET.import();
var allUnicodeLetters = ['Lu', 'Ll', 'Lt', 'Lm', 'Lo'].map(fromUnicodeGeneralCategory).reduce(union);
var allAllowedCharacters = union(allUnicodeLetters, fromString("'- _"));
var regex = new RegExp(toRegex(complement(allAllowedCharacters)), 'g');
```

Then you could use `str = str.replace(regex, '')` and it would remove all special characters except for the ones you want to allow including symbols like dingbats.

**Edit:** Just realized you may also want to allow numbers, if so you could use the following, which was obtained by adding `'Nd'` and `'Nl'` in the method above:

```
var regex = /[\u0000-\u001f!-&(-,.-/:-@[-^`{-©«-´¶-¹»-¿×÷˂-˅˒-˟˥-˫˭˯-\u036f͵\u0378-\u0379;-΅·\u038b\u038d\u03a2϶҂-\u0489\u0524-\u0530\u0557-\u0558՚-\u0560\u0588-\u05cf\u05eb-\u05ef׳-\u0620\u064b-\u065f٪-٭\u0670۔\u06d6-\u06e4\u06e7-\u06ed۽-۾܀-\u070f\u0711\u0730-\u074c\u07a6-\u07b0\u07b2-\u07bf\u07eb-\u07f3߶-߹\u07fb-\u0903\u093a-\u093c\u093e-\u094f\u0951-\u0957\u0962-॥॰\u0973-\u097a\u0980-\u0984\u098d-\u098e\u0991-\u0992\u09a9\u09b1\u09b3-\u09b5\u09ba-\u09bc\u09be-\u09cd\u09cf-\u09db\u09de\u09e2-\u09e5৲-\u0a04\u0a0b-\u0a0e\u0a11-\u0a12\u0a29\u0a31\u0a34\u0a37\u0a3a-\u0a58\u0a5d\u0a5f-\u0a65\u0a70-\u0a71\u0a75-\u0a84\u0a8e\u0a92\u0aa9\u0ab1\u0ab4\u0aba-\u0abc\u0abe-\u0acf\u0ad1-\u0adf\u0ae2-\u0ae5\u0af0-\u0b04\u0b0d-\u0b0e\u0b11-\u0b12\u0b29\u0b31\u0b34\u0b3a-\u0b3c\u0b3e-\u0b5b\u0b5e\u0b62-\u0b65୰\u0b72-\u0b82\u0b84\u0b8b-\u0b8d\u0b91\u0b96-\u0b98\u0b9b\u0b9d\u0ba0-\u0ba2\u0ba5-\u0ba7\u0bab-\u0bad\u0bba-\u0bcf\u0bd1-\u0be5௰-\u0c04\u0c0d\u0c11\u0c29\u0c34\u0c3a-\u0c3c\u0c3e-\u0c57\u0c5a-\u0c5f\u0c62-\u0c65\u0c70-\u0c84\u0c8d\u0c91\u0ca9\u0cb4\u0cba-\u0cbc\u0cbe-\u0cdd\u0cdf\u0ce2-\u0ce5\u0cf0-\u0d04\u0d0d\u0d11\u0d29\u0d3a-\u0d3c\u0d3e-\u0d5f\u0d62-\u0d65൰-൹\u0d80-\u0d84\u0d97-\u0d99\u0db2\u0dbc\u0dbe-\u0dbf\u0dc7-\u0e00\u0e31\u0e34-฿\u0e47-๏๚-\u0e80\u0e83\u0e85-\u0e86\u0e89\u0e8b-\u0e8c\u0e8e-\u0e93\u0e98\u0ea0\u0ea4\u0ea6\u0ea8-\u0ea9\u0eac\u0eb1\u0eb4-\u0ebc\u0ebe-\u0ebf\u0ec5\u0ec7-\u0ecf\u0eda-\u0edb\u0ede-\u0eff༁-༟༪-\u0f3f\u0f48\u0f6d-\u0f87\u0f8c-\u0fff\u102b-\u103e၊-၏\u1056-\u1059\u105e-\u1060\u1062-\u1064\u1067-\u106d\u1071-\u1074\u1082-\u108d\u108f\u109a-႟\u10c6-\u10cf჻\u10fd-\u10ff\u115a-\u115e\u11a3-\u11a7\u11fa-\u11ff\u1249\u124e-\u124f\u1257\u1259\u125e-\u125f\u1289\u128e-\u128f\u12b1\u12b6-\u12b7\u12bf\u12c1\u12c6-\u12c7\u12d7\u1311\u1316-\u1317\u135b-\u137f᎐-\u139f\u13f5-\u1400᙭-᙮\u1677-\u1680᚛-\u169f᛫-᛭\u16f1-\u16ff\u170d\u1712-\u171f\u1732-\u173f\u1752-\u175f\u176d\u1771-\u177f\u17b4-៖៘-៛\u17dd-\u17df\u17ea-\u180f\u181a-\u181f\u1878-\u187f\u18a9\u18ab-\u18ff\u191d-᥅\u196e-\u196f\u1975-\u197f\u19aa-\u19c0\u19c8-\u19cf\u19da-᧿\u1a17-\u1b04\u1b34-\u1b44\u1b4c-\u1b4f᭚-\u1b82\u1ba1-\u1bad\u1bba-\u1bff\u1c24-᰿\u1c4a-\u1c4c᱾-\u1cff\u1dc0-\u1dff\u1f16-\u1f17\u1f1e-\u1f1f\u1f46-\u1f47\u1f4e-\u1f4f\u1f58\u1f5a\u1f5c\u1f5e\u1f7e-\u1f7f\u1fb5᾽᾿-῁\u1fc5῍-῏\u1fd4-\u1fd5\u1fdc-῟῭-\u1ff1\u1ff5´-⁰\u2072-⁾₀-\u208f\u2095-℁℃-℆℈-℉℔№-℘℞-℣℥℧℩℮℺-℻⅀-⅄⅊-⅍⅏-⅟\u2189-\u2bff\u2c2f\u2c5f\u2c70\u2c7e-\u2c7f⳥-⳿\u2d26-\u2d2f\u2d66-\u2d6e\u2d70-\u2d7f\u2d97-\u2d9f\u2da7\u2daf\u2db7\u2dbf\u2dc7\u2dcf\u2dd7\u2ddf-⸮⸰-〄〈-〠\u302a-〰〶-〷〽-\u3040\u3097-゜゠・\u3100-\u3104\u312e-\u3130\u318f-㆟\u31b8-\u31ef㈀-㏿\u4db6-䷿\u9fc4-\u9fff\ua48d-\ua4ff꘍-꘏\ua62c-\ua63f\ua660-\ua661\ua66f-꙾\ua698-꜖꜠-꜡꞉-꞊\ua78d-\ua7fa\ua802\ua806\ua80b\ua823-\ua83f꡴-\ua881\ua8b4-꣏\ua8da-\ua8ff\ua926-꤯\ua947-\ua9ff\uaa29-\uaa3f\uaa43\uaa4c-\uaa4f\uaa5a-\uabff\ud7a4-\ud7ff\ud840-\ud868\udc00-\uf8ff\ufa2e-\ufa2f\ufa6b-\ufa6f\ufada-\ufaff\ufb07-\ufb12\ufb18-\ufb1c\ufb1e﬩\ufb37\ufb3d\ufb3f\ufb42\ufb45\ufbb2-\ufbd2﴾-\ufd4f\ufd90-\ufd91\ufdc8-\ufdef﷼-\ufe6f\ufe75\ufefd-／：-＠［-｀｛-･\uffbf-\uffc1\uffc8-\uffc9\uffd0-\uffd1\uffd8-\uffd9\uffdd-\uffff]|[\ud803-\ud807\ud80a-\ud834\ud836-\ud83f\ud86a-\ud87d\ud87f-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|\ud800[\udc0c\udc27\udc3b\udc3e\udc4e-\udc4f\udc5e-\udc7f\udcfb-\udd3f\udd75-\ude7f\ude9d-\ude9f\uded1-\udeff\udf1f-\udf2f\udf4b-\udf7f\udf9e-\udf9f\udfc4-\udfc7\udfd0\udfd6-\udfff]|\ud801[\udc9e-\udc9f\udcaa-\udfff]|\ud802[\udc06-\udc07\udc09\udc36\udc39-\udc3b\udc3d-\udc3e\udc40-\udcff\udd16-\udd1f\udd3a-\uddff\ude01-\ude0f\ude14\ude18\ude34-\udfff]|\ud808[\udf6f-\udfff]|\ud809[\udc63-\udfff]|\ud835[\udc55\udc9d\udca0-\udca1\udca3-\udca4\udca7-\udca8\udcad\udcba\udcbc\udcc4\udd06\udd0b-\udd0c\udd15\udd1d\udd3a\udd3f\udd45\udd47-\udd49\udd51\udea6-\udea7\udec1\udedb\udefb\udf15\udf35\udf4f\udf6f\udf89\udfa9\udfc3\udfcc-\udfcd]|\ud869[\uded7-\udfff]|\ud87e[\ude1e-\udfff]|[\ud800-\ud83f\ud869-\udbff]/g;
```

Comment: thank you,  in case like this `str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9'-_ ü]/g, "");`  how would i include that `ü`?

Comment: See my edit, I just added a regex that you can use the way you want to.  As for how to just add the `ü`, what you have should actually work just fine (except that the `-` after the `'` should be escaped).  Where you will run into issues is when you try to use a character like that as a part of a range in a character class.

Comment: @tq Glad I could help, it was a pretty fun problem.  If this answer solved your problem you can accept it by clicking the outline of the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no unicode character class for Regular expressions in JavaScript, but you can either include/exclude all the characters by yourself by doing something like this:

```
str = str.replace(/[!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\{\}\?<>\+:;",\.\\]/g, "");
```

Or use a library like [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/)

Comment: thank you,  are you saying that i should just filter out what i dont want?

Comment: @tq yeah that works if you know exactly what characters you don't want

Comment: how would i strip out ding bat symbols?

Comment: @tq the same way you would strip out any other symbol

Comment: i cant seem to catch these ` ♥★☐↑`

Comment: to catch hearts and other symbols i need to find unicode `.replace(/[\u2764]/g, "");`

Comment: This approach doesn't scale very well, as really meeting the requirement would involve adding hundreds if not thousands of Unicode characters as well.

Comment: @F.J how is that any different from your answer?

Comment: @fiction Well, in my answer I actually do it and explain how the library could be used to solve the problem.

Comment: @fiction I hope you understand why I deleted the comment I just did.