# Is it possible to let \w regexp pattern to allow characters such as é as well? If not, what alternatives are there?

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets say I have  a regexp that looks like:

```
\w+
```

Then this string would pass:

```
helloworld
```

However this won't:

```
héllowörld
```

It will stop at `é` (and the`ö`will break it as well)  even though for a human `héllowörld` doesn't sound so far fetched as a single word.

Is there a way I can improve `\w` so it will also include special word characters? Or do I have to append every special latin character into my regexp like this into:

```
[\wéèåöä...........]+
```

Because that doesn't seem like the best option to try and figure out what all the different special latin characters there are in the world that would be reasonable.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. It doesn't match non-english character.

Read this post for [Regular expression to match non-english characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)

Comment: Fast answer, awesome!

Comment: Shouldn't this link to another answer just be a vote to close as dupe?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use an inverse method to match non-english among the other characters. Check this out

```
var string = "你好 κόσμος привет šđčßŁłćž çë asgfgrtzj 657 #$%&/()=?*!";
```

The pattern below

```
var pattern = /([^0-9]+)/gi;
```

will exclude all numbers

```
你好 κόσμος привет šđčßŁłćž çë asgfgrtzj #$%&/()=?*!";
```

adding special characters from the above to the pattern

```
var pattern = /([^0-9#$%&/()=?*!]+)/gi;
```

the final string would look as following

```
你好 κόσμος привет šđčßŁłćž çë asgfgrtzj
```

Comment: This is also interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @corgrath Though, it still doesn't deserve an up-vote :)) You're welcome :)

Comment: A question though, why write 0-9 and not \d?

Comment: @corgrath Well, it's a bit longer story and I could explain it later :) In general, `[0-9]` `\d` and `[:digit:]` are synonyms but depending on the regex engine they may behave differently. I prefer using `[0-9]`