# Match words in a string and make them lowercase

Tags: javascript, regex, match, lowercase

I have this example string:

```
var string = 'This is a süPer NICE Sentence, am I right?';
```

The result has to be:

```
this, is, süper, nice, sentence
```

Requirements:

1. 5 words max,
2. words that contain at least 2 characters
3. comma separated
4. takes care of special characters such as **ü** **this is not currently happening**
5. all in lowercase **this is not currently happening**

This is my current script: (you can test it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ox8ux408/1/))

```
var string = 'This is a süPer NICE Sentence, am I right?';
var words;
words = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g,function(str){return '';});
words = words.match(/\w{2,}/g);

if(words != null) {
    //5 words maximum
    words = words.slice(0,5);
    if(words.length) {
        console.log(words.join(', ')); //should print: this, is, süper, nice, sentence
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to convert the matched words into lowercase before the `join`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is definitely `toLowerCase()`, but I think the best place to run it is right at the end rather than the beginning (fewer items to operate on):

```
if(words != null) {
    //5 words maximum
    words = words.slice(0,5);
    if(words.length) {
        console.log(words.join(', ').toLowerCase()); //here
    }
}
```

toLowerCase() is, as far as I know, unicode-friendly. Your regex is stripping anything not a-z,A-Z.

Asker found this link helpful for resolving regex issue: [Regular expression to match non-English characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)

Comment: toLowerCase() is deleting special characters (ü)... I updated the example to consider that as well.

Comment: @andufo `words = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g,function(str){return '';});` is what is deleting those characters.

Comment: how could the regex consider special characters as well?

Comment: @andufo I'm not great with regex, maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters Might have to exclude numbers too... not too sure.

Comment: Just fyi this is not correct becuase `string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g,function(str){return '';});` will leave `This is a sPer NICE Sentence am I right` **eating away** `ü` in `süPer`

Comment: @anubhava you're right, but I used the solution available in the link for the correct conversion which ended up being the perfect regex.

Comment: Can you update the question with your reworked solution to benefit others.

Answer (score 1):

Just use .toLowerCase() .

```
var string = 'This is a süPer NICE Sentence, am I right?';
string = string.toLowerCase();
var words = string.split(' ');

//5 words maximum
words = words.slice(0,5);

console.log(words.join(', ')); //should print: this, is, super, nice, sentence
```

The special characters were being filtered out by the regex - if you know the words are separated by a whitespace, just use string.split(' ');

Comment: sorry, I added a special consideration. the toLowerCase() is deleting special characters (ü)... I updated the example.

Comment: Just noticed that `replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g,function(str){return '';})` is removing the caracter. How could I consider the ü character in that regex?

Answer (score 0):

Just lowercase the string from the start

```
string.toLowerCase().replace(...
```

Comment: The problem with the toLowerCase() method is that it deletes special characters such as: Ü

Comment: @andufo "abvcÜ".toLowerCase() === "abvcü".

Comment: strange... I just tested the example at https://jsfiddle.net/ox8ux408/1/ and the ü gets removed.

Comment: That would be your reg exp removing the ü not the toLowerCase()

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could map the word array to a lowercase string using Array#map.

`console.log(words.map(function(word) { return word.toLowerCase(); }).join(', '));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toLowerCase` method of a `string` to first convert the string into lower case and then do all the manipulations you need to do on the string.

eg: `var string = 'This is a suPer NICE Sentence, am I right?'.toLowerCase();`