# Angular slugify leaving dash at the end

Tags: angularjs

Remove accents and symbols slugify, but leaving dash at the end.

I would also share the same function between controllers , how do?

code:

```
$scope.slugify = function(slug){
    str = slug.replace("-");
    str = angular.lowercase(str);
    str = str.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "-");        
    $scope.item.slug = str;
}
```

Example:

source: Neymar the best player!

```
 return: neymar-the-best-player-
```

[Resolved]

i found this: https://github.com/paulsmith/angular-slugify

Answer (score 2):

Main problem:

> Remove accents and symbols slugify, but **leaving dash at the end**.

Before we go to the main problem, there are several parts of you code that needs mending.

1. The first `replace()` statement, works for dashes that between any other strings, but would definitely be a problem if dashes are placed in both ends of a string.

e.g. `'-Some-Text-'` results to `'undefinedSome-Textundefined'`

To solve this problem you need to add the second argument for `replace()` with an empty string.

From:

```
str = slug.replace("-");
```

To:

```
str = slug.replace('-', '');
```

2. The second `replace()` statement has a regular expression flag representing, `i`, representing for a case-insensitive search. While your regular expression statement suggests an `A-Z` (uppercase expression), this in fact is redundant, since you've already modified the string into a lower case. So the statement should be changed:

From:

```
str = str.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "-");
```

To:

```
str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, "-");
```

3. Now for the main problem, you're simply missing a dash trimming function for both ends of the string.

Add this replace statement after the code in #2

```
str = str.replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '');
```

---

From what I see in your code, this seems to be more of a reusable function rather than something that can be attributed to a controller function. You can create a service for this specific function instead and inject it in your controller.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Dsmtiadso88Bf1AIOIZ?p=preview)**

```
  .controller('SluggerController', function($scope, slugify) {

    $scope.slug = 'Neymar the best player!';
    $scope.item = { slug: '' };

    $scope.slugify = function(slug) {
      $scope.item.slug = slugify(slug);
    };

  })

  .factory('slugify', function() {
    return function(text) {
      return angular.lowercase(text)
        .replace('-', '')
        .replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, '-')
        .replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '');
    };
  });
```

**UPDATE:**

Since you don't want to include unicode characters as dashed characters then you can incorporate this with #2.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/zHBHwscHzDZAp1XsnMhV?p=preview)**

Instead of:

```
str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, "-");
```

Change it to:

```
str = str.replace(/[^\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w0-9]/g, '-');
```

As for how I got the regular expression, you can refer to this **[SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters#comment-19644791)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But tested with some accents and one answer was this:

Input: Marco Riescão
Output: marco-riesc-o   the right would be: marco-riescao

Comment: That is the limitation of your second `replace()` statement, even with the solution you have written above does not work with unicode letters.

Comment: The accents are now showing. marco-riescão, Missed taking the accents, I think.

Comment: What I had before, I took all signs and accents , that you did , it was great, but the accents are still there ..

Answer (score 1):

To make it public there is a necessary step to return something. Then you can wrap it as a `constant` and inject in any controller.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, slugify) {
  $scope.show = function(){
    alert(slugify($scope.someText));
  }
});
app.constant('slugify', function(slug){
    str = slug.replace("-");
    str = angular.lowercase(str);
    str = str.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "-");        
    return  str;
});
```

Also from the nature of the transformation applied by function it fits the pattern of `filter`.

```
app.filter('slugifyFilter', function(){
  return function(slug){
    str = slug.replace("-");
    str = angular.lowercase(str);
    str = str.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "-");        
    return  str;
  }
});
```

And use like this in template

```
 {{someText | slugifyFilter}}
```

See it in action in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uH9PVJ8UxLfZTZD1dG7V)