# Processing accented Unicode characters with python regex module

Tags: python, regex, string, utf-8

I have following two functions that works perfectly fine with ASCII strings and use the `re` module:

```
import re

def findWord(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b{0}.*?\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).findall


def replace_keyword(w, c, x):
    return re.sub(r"\b({0}\S*)".format(w), r'<mark style="background-color:{0}">\1</mark>'.format(c), x, flags=re.I)
```

However, they fail on using the `utf-8` encoded strings with accented characters. On searching further, I found that the `regex` module is better suited for Unicode strings and hence I have been trying to port this to use `regex` for the last couple of hours but nothing seem to be working. This is what I have as of now:

```
import regex

def findWord(w):
    return regex.compile(r'\b{0}.*?\b'.format(w), flags=regex.IGNORECASE|regex.UNICODE).findall

def replace_keyword(w, c, x):
    return regex.sub(r"\b({0}\S*)".format(w), r'<mark style="background-color:{0}">\1</mark>'.format(c), x, flags=regex.IGNORECASE|regex.UNICODE)
```

However, on using an accented (not normalized) `utf-8` encoded string, I keep getting an `ordinal not in range` error.

EDIT: The suggested possible duplicate question:  [Regular expression to match non-English characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters) doesn't solve my problem. I want to use the python `re`/`regex` module. Secondly, I want to get the `find` and `replace` functions working using python.

EDIT: I am using python 2

EDIT: If you feel you can help me get these two functions working using Python 3 please let me know. I hope I will be able to invoke python 3 for using just these 2 functions through my python 2 script.

Comment: "they fail on using the utf-8 encoded strings" Yes, yes they do. This is to be expected since they work on text and UTF-8 encoded strings aren't text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match non-English characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?  What do you mean by "UTF-8 encoded string"?  In Python 2, strings are ASCII-only, in Python 3 strings allow any Unicode codepoint.  Encodings like UTF-8 are relevant when reading in or writing out text, inside Python a string doesn't have an encoding, per se.

Comment: @dimo414: Thanks for this info "inside Python a string doesn't have an encoding, per se". In short, I have accented characters present in my string and I want to get these two functions (find and replace) working for them in python 2

Comment: @TheWanderer: You need to operate on Unicode string and enable re.UNICODE to make the tokens `\b`, `\w`, `\d`, `\s` work with Unicode character.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I am not sure if I understand correctly. Will I be able to preserve the accents ?

Comment: This is a great question, but if you are dealing with non-ASCII text I highly recommend that you move to Python 3.

Comment: @dotancohen: Can you please try to get this working using Python 3? I am assuming I will be able to invoke python 3 script from my python 2 which will just run these two functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am headed somewhere. I am trying to get this working without using the modules `re` or `regex` but plain python:

```
found_keywords = []
for word in keyword_list:
    if word.lower() in article_text.lower():
         found_keywords.append(word)

for word in found_keywords:  # highlight the found keyword in the text
    article_text = article_text.lower().replace(word.lower(), '<mark style="background-color:%s">%s</mark>' % (yellow_color, word))
```

Now, I just have to somehow replace found keywords in a case-insensitive manner and I will be good to go.

Just help me with this last step of replacing keywords in a case-insensitive manner without using `re` or `regex` so that it works for accented strings.