# How to match language specific chars in a regex?

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I know that `\w` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` or `[\p{L}\p{N}_]` if compiled with `(?u)`.

The french language has 42 characters `[a-zàâæçéêëîïôœùûüÿ]`. Is it possible to build my regex according to my `locale`.

How can I match `[a-zàâæçéêëîïôœùûüÿ]` with `\w`?

A partial answer would be to use unicode regexes with `\p{Latin}`.

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you are using.  You will get a better answer this way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match non-English characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)

Comment: It depends on your regular expression engine, but `\w` typically is, or can be made, locale-sensitive.

Comment: @chepner Is it also the case on regex101?

Comment: regex101 seems to only use the `u` modifier for matching Unicode characters, which might be more general than you want. (For example, `ø` is not in the French alphabet, but `/\w/u` would match it.)

Comment: The question is now tagged 'perl' and 'pcre'. Which of the two are you asking about?

Comment: @reinierpost Both actually. regex101 which I am using quite often is `pcre`, on the shell I prefer `perl` over `sed`, but I am also using `ag` which is `pcre`...

Comment: OK thanks for the info, then the tags are perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `l` modifier makes the match locale-aware:

```
"foo" ~= m/\w/l;
```

Instead of using `l` directly, though, use `use locale` per mob's link.

Comment: Is `l` a `Perl` specific flag?

Comment: Possibly? There is no standard set of flags, which is why regular-expression questions require a specific language tag.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlre.pod#Character-set-modifiers -- recommends that you don't use the `/l` modifier directly. Instead, `use locale` and any regex compiled in the scope of your locale will implicitly use the `'/l` modifier.