# Creating regex for javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am keen on using both `[^\u0000-\u007F]+` and `^[A-Za-z0-9._-](?:[A-Za-z0-9._ -]*[A-Za-z0-9._-])?$` as a one regex but it's so complicated, I just couldn't make it work? Any ideas how to integrate both?

I want to use JavaScript version for client-side verification and Php version for server-side verification.

Comment: Mind telling us *what you intend to match* instead of just the RegEx?

Comment: `[^\u0000-\u007F]+` this is for non-english alphabetical characters such as `àèéìòóùà` and this `^[A-Za-z0-9._-](?:[A-Za-z0-9._ -]*[A-Za-z0-9._-])?$` is for only letters, numbers, dot, dash, underscore and no whitespaces on the beginning and end.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Provide strings that should match and those that should not match. What you tried to achieve that and what went wrong.

Comment: The two patterns are mutually exclusive, so you can't. (take a look at the ascii table.)

Comment: @Rough: not only! `[^\u0000-\u007f]` is for all that is not in the ascii table.

Comment: Just an idea: what if instead of `[^\u0000-\u007F]` we use `[\x80-\xFF]`? Try [`^[\x80-\xFF\w.-](?:[\x80-\xFF\w. -]*[\x80-\xFF\w.-])?$`](https://regex101.com/r/zI1gP8/1).

Comment: `^[A-Za-z0-9._-](?:[A-Za-z0-9._ -]*[A-Za-z0-9._-])?$` this codes helps me a lot. User can't put anything else than letters, numbers, dot, dash, underscore. Also can't use whitespaces at the beginning and end. But you know there are another alphabets with their own characters. Italian has these: `àèéìòóùà`. So I want these letters to be also valid. I came across [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters/150078#150078) and I found `[^\u0000-\u007F]+` this code helps me. And now I'm trying to found out using them at once.

Comment: in this case add them in the class instead of trying to find a range, probably this: `^[a-zàèéìòóùà0-9._-]+(?: [a-zàèéìòóùà0-9._-]+)*$` with a case insensitive flag (but your question stay very unclear).

Comment: @stribizhev this time cant use those: `Ğ ğ Ş ş İ ı ą ć ę ł ń ó ś ź ż Ż Ź Ś Ó Ń Ł Ę Ć Ą` @Casimir et Hippolyte I can't because there are lots of letters.

Comment: @Rough: yes, the reason is that PHP regex does not support `\uXXXX` notation. However, there is [a workaround](http://ideone.com/OsOQp4). This [`^[\u0080-\uFFFF\w.-](?:[\u0080-\uFFFF\w. -]*[\u0080-\uFFFF\w.-])?$`](https://regex101.com/r/zI1gP8/2) would match those letters. In JS, this regex can be used as is in literal notation.

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you. Couldn't do it myself. Literally spent hours. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the remaining part of the Unicode table with `[\u0080-\uFFFF]` instead of `[^\u0000-\u007F]`.

In JS, `\w` matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, I suggest using

```
^[\u0080-\uFFFF\w.-](?:[\u0080-\uFFFF\w. -]*[\u0080-\uFFFF\w.-])?$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI1gP8/2)

In PHP, just use [`\p{L}` with `/u` modifier](https://regex101.com/r/zI1gP8/3):

```
$re = '/^[\p{L}0-9_.-](?:[\p{L}0-9_. -]*[\p{L}0-9_.-])?$/u'; 
          ^^^^^           ^^^^^          ^^^^^           ^
```

It looks like no one likes `\uXXXX` in PHP. @nhahtdh confirms there may be issues with matching same code points.

Comment: Your recommendations for the first regex is terrible. If we want to match characters outside the ASCII range, you must always use `u` flag to correctly interpret the input. The solution with json_decode only happens to work, since the range encodes to UTF-8 is `\xC2\x80-\xEF\xBF\xBF`, which contains the range `\x80-\xEF`, which covers up to 3-byte UTF-8 encoded sequences. I think your answer should be edited to contain only the second solution.

Comment: In PHP, if you want to specify character by code point, use `\x{hh...h}` syntax. It also works in character class, but the range is limited by the mode (in default mode, up to the size of the code unit - in PHP is 0xFF, in `u` mode, up to 0x10FFFF).

Comment: `\p{L}` is a correct solution. `json_decode` on `\u0080-\uFFFF` is an unsafe solution without `u` flag - just use `\x{hh...h}` notation.

Comment: Please don't try to make the same regex runs on both PHP and JS. There are fundamental differences in how they interpret the regex and the string representation in the two languages. Your idea only happens to work with this case - if the end points are different, the code may give you unwanted surprises.