# html data-filter attribute international characters

Tags: javascript, html, special-characters

I couldn't find solution anywhere else: I am using data-filter attribute to filter my images in gallery by folder name:

```
<a class="" href="#" data-filter=".strecha">
```

but if the folder name contains any international characters (ěščřžýáíé), it is not working.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I have already tried php function iconv

Comment: [RegEx for non-english characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters) See if this helps

The answer says you may use `[^\x00-\x7F]+` to include every character

Comment: also not if you use the ASCAII codes like à = &#224; ??

Comment: OK, but how do I implement this [^\x00-\x7F]+ ?