# Find last word of a string that has special characters

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to add a `span` tag to the last word of a string. It works if the string has no special characters. I can't figure out the correct regex for it.

```
$string = "Onun Mesajı";
echo preg_replace("~\W\w+\s*\S?$~", ' <span>' . '\\0' . '</span>', $string);
```

Here is the Turkish character set : `ÇŞĞÜÖİçşğüöı`

Comment: might this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters

Comment: [`preg_replace("~\w+\s*$~u", ' <span>' . '\\0' . '</span>', $string);`](http://ideone.com/XYVvvW)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `/u` modifier to allow processing Unicode characters in the pattern and input string.

```
preg_replace('~\w+\s*$~u', '<span>$0</span>', $string); 
                       ^
```

[Full PHP demo](http://ideone.com/F0dmM6):

```
$string = "Onun Mesajı";
echo preg_replace("~\w+\s*$~u", '<span>$0</span>', $string);
```

Also, the regex you need is just `\w+\s*$`:

- `\w+` - 1 or more alphanumerics
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace (trailing)
- `$` - end of string

Since I removed the `\W` from the regex, there is no need to "hardcode" the leading space in the replacement string (removed, too).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `u` modifier for regular expressions to set the engine into unicode mode:

```
<?php
$subject = "Onun äöüß Mesajı";
$pattern = '/\w+\s*?$/u';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '<span>\\0</span>', $subject);
```

The output is:

```
Onun äöüß <span>Mesajı</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do the trick for you, and is a lot shorter then the other solutions:

```
[ ](.*?$)
```

Here is an example of it:

```
$string = "Onun Mes*ÇŞĞÜÖİçşğüöıajı";
echo preg_replace('~[ ](.*?$)~', ' <span>' .'${1}'. '</span>', $string);
```

Will echo out:

```
Onun <span>Mes*ÇŞĞÜÖİçşğüöıajı</span>
```

The way this regex works is that we look for any characters without space in lazy mode `[ ].*?`. 
then we add the `$` identifier, so it matches from the end of the string instead.

Comment: could you please explain why this works? Might help OP more, if he understands how the regex works. Thanks :-)

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Yeah sorry @Lino, just extended my answer with some text to explain it