# How can I extend regular expression to accept unicode characters?

Tags: regex, unicode

I have a simple regular expression matching all letters repeated one after another:

```
Pattern: \w* 
Subject: Pyry
```

[ http://regexr.com/3ctl1 ]

I want to extend my expression to accept UTF-8 signs like `ą`, `ę` or `ö`. How should I edit the expression to match `Pöyry` or `Mąka` subjects?

In particular I'm interested in Angular.js implementation of the regex.

**UPDATE**

In fact I don't want to extend that simple pattern, but something more complex.

Let's say this: `\w[\w\-\–]*\w`

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) is a form where angular flavor expressions can be tested.

Comment: What regex flavor? JavaScript? regexr.com only supports JavaScript regex flavor, BTW. *RegExr uses your browser's RegExp engine for matching, and its syntax highlighting and documentation reflect the JavaScript RegExp standard.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match non-English characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Angular.js and .NET

Comment: In .NET, `\w` matches all Unicode letters, digits and an underscore. In JS, you will have to use XRegExp with `\d`, `\pL` and `_`, or "equivalent". Or do you need the same pattern to work in JS and .NET? Can you use a 3rd party library in JS?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've just checked, you're right in .NET there's match. I thought it doesn't work in both Angular and .NET because I use this regex to validate input and Angular is first on my validation hierarchy.

Comment: Regex in .NET is Unicode aware. If you want to restrict the `\w` to match only `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, use the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` flag. However, I think you need the opposite, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in .NET, `\w` matches all Unicode letters, digits and an underscore.

You can use this one and the same regular expression in Angular and .NET to match one or more alphanumerics/underscore characters:

```
[_0-9a-zA-Z\xAA\xB5\xBA\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u052F\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0620-\u064A\u066E\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5\u06E6\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07CA-\u07EA\u07F4\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u0815\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08A0-\u08B2\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0980\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09F0\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32\u0A33\u0A35\u0A36\u0A38\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E\u0B9F\u0BA3\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58\u0C59\u0C60\u0C61\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0\u0CE1\u0CF1\u0CF2\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D60\u0D61\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E81\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F4\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16F1-\u16F8\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1950-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19C1-\u19C7\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1AA7\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE\u1BAF\u1BBA-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C4D-\u1C4F\u1C5A-\u1C7D\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF1\u1CF5\u1CF6\u1D00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2183\u2184\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CEE\u2CF2\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2E2F\u3005\u3006\u3031-\u3035\u303B\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FCC\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA61F\uA62A\uA62B\uA640-\uA66E\uA67F-\uA69D\uA6A0-\uA6E5\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA78E\uA790-\uA7AD\uA7B0\uA7B1\uA7F7-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA90A-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uA9CF\uA9E0-\uA9E4\uA9E6-\uA9EF\uA9FA-\uA9FE\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA7E-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEA\uAAF2-\uAAF4\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB5F\uAB64\uAB65\uABC0-\uABE2\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40\uFB41\uFB43\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]+
```

You can check the regex at [regexstrom.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) to see how it works in .NET, and [JS regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iV3tI9/2).

It contains all Unicode letter ranges, and also `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`.

Here is how to make it more readable in JS:

```js
var pL = "\\xAA\\xB5\\xBA\\xC0-\\xD6\\xD8-\\xF6\\xF8-\\u02C1\\u02C6-\\u02D1\\u02E0-\\u02E4\\u02EC\\u02EE\\u0370-\\u0374\\u0376\\u0377\\u037A-\\u037D\\u037F\\u0386\\u0388-\\u038A\\u038C\\u038E-\\u03A1\\u03A3-\\u03F5\\u03F7-\\u0481\\u048A-\\u052F\\u0531-\\u0556\\u0559\\u0561-\\u0587\\u05D0-\\u05EA\\u05F0-\\u05F2\\u0620-\\u064A\\u066E\\u066F\\u0671-\\u06D3\\u06D5\\u06E5\\u06E6\\u06EE\\u06EF\\u06FA-\\u06FC\\u06FF\\u0710\\u0712-\\u072F\\u074D-\\u07A5\\u07B1\\u07CA-\\u07EA\\u07F4\\u07F5\\u07FA\\u0800-\\u0815\\u081A\\u0824\\u0828\\u0840-\\u0858\\u08A0-\\u08B2\\u0904-\\u0939\\u093D\\u0950\\u0958-\\u0961\\u0971-\\u0980\\u0985-\\u098C\\u098F\\u0990\\u0993-\\u09A8\\u09AA-\\u09B0\\u09B2\\u09B6-\\u09B9\\u09BD\\u09CE\\u09DC\\u09DD\\u09DF-\\u09E1\\u09F0\\u09F1\\u0A05-\\u0A0A\\u0A0F\\u0A10\\u0A13-\\u0A28\\u0A2A-\\u0A30\\u0A32\\u0A33\\u0A35\\u0A36\\u0A38\\u0A39\\u0A59-\\u0A5C\\u0A5E\\u0A72-\\u0A74\\u0A85-\\u0A8D\\u0A8F-\\u0A91\\u0A93-\\u0AA8\\u0AAA-\\u0AB0\\u0AB2\\u0AB3\\u0AB5-\\u0AB9\\u0ABD\\u0AD0\\u0AE0\\u0AE1\\u0B05-\\u0B0C\\u0B0F\\u0B10\\u0B13-\\u0B28\\u0B2A-\\u0B30\\u0B32\\u0B33\\u0B35-\\u0B39\\u0B3D\\u0B5C\\u0B5D\\u0B5F-\\u0B61\\u0B71\\u0B83\\u0B85-\\u0B8A\\u0B8E-\\u0B90\\u0B92-\\u0B95\\u0B99\\u0B9A\\u0B9C\\u0B9E\\u0B9F\\u0BA3\\u0BA4\\u0BA8-\\u0BAA\\u0BAE-\\u0BB9\\u0BD0\\u0C05-\\u0C0C\\u0C0E-\\u0C10\\u0C12-\\u0C28\\u0C2A-\\u0C39\\u0C3D\\u0C58\\u0C59\\u0C60\\u0C61\\u0C85-\\u0C8C\\u0C8E-\\u0C90\\u0C92-\\u0CA8\\u0CAA-\\u0CB3\\u0CB5-\\u0CB9\\u0CBD\\u0CDE\\u0CE0\\u0CE1\\u0CF1\\u0CF2\\u0D05-\\u0D0C\\u0D0E-\\u0D10\\u0D12-\\u0D3A\\u0D3D\\u0D4E\\u0D60\\u0D61\\u0D7A-\\u0D7F\\u0D85-\\u0D96\\u0D9A-\\u0DB1\\u0DB3-\\u0DBB\\u0DBD\\u0DC0-\\u0DC6\\u0E01-\\u0E30\\u0E32\\u0E33\\u0E40-\\u0E46\\u0E81\\u0E82\\u0E84\\u0E87\\u0E88\\u0E8A\\u0E8D\\u0E94-\\u0E97\\u0E99-\\u0E9F\\u0EA1-\\u0EA3\\u0EA5\\u0EA7\\u0EAA\\u0EAB\\u0EAD-\\u0EB0\\u0EB2\\u0EB3\\u0EBD\\u0EC0-\\u0EC4\\u0EC6\\u0EDC-\\u0EDF\\u0F00\\u0F40-\\u0F47\\u0F49-\\u0F6C\\u0F88-\\u0F8C\\u1000-\\u102A\\u103F\\u1050-\\u1055\\u105A-\\u105D\\u1061\\u1065\\u1066\\u106E-\\u1070\\u1075-\\u1081\\u108E\\u10A0-\\u10C5\\u10C7\\u10CD\\u10D0-\\u10FA\\u10FC-\\u1248\\u124A-\\u124D\\u1250-\\u1256\\u1258\\u125A-\\u125D\\u1260-\\u1288\\u128A-\\u128D\\u1290-\\u12B0\\u12B2-\\u12B5\\u12B8-\\u12BE\\u12C0\\u12C2-\\u12C5\\u12C8-\\u12D6\\u12D8-\\u1310\\u1312-\\u1315\\u1318-\\u135A\\u1380-\\u138F\\u13A0-\\u13F4\\u1401-\\u166C\\u166F-\\u167F\\u1681-\\u169A\\u16A0-\\u16EA\\u16F1-\\u16F8\\u1700-\\u170C\\u170E-\\u1711\\u1720-\\u1731\\u1740-\\u1751\\u1760-\\u176C\\u176E-\\u1770\\u1780-\\u17B3\\u17D7\\u17DC\\u1820-\\u1877\\u1880-\\u18A8\\u18AA\\u18B0-\\u18F5\\u1900-\\u191E\\u1950-\\u196D\\u1970-\\u1974\\u1980-\\u19AB\\u19C1-\\u19C7\\u1A00-\\u1A16\\u1A20-\\u1A54\\u1AA7\\u1B05-\\u1B33\\u1B45-\\u1B4B\\u1B83-\\u1BA0\\u1BAE\\u1BAF\\u1BBA-\\u1BE5\\u1C00-\\u1C23\\u1C4D-\\u1C4F\\u1C5A-\\u1C7D\\u1CE9-\\u1CEC\\u1CEE-\\u1CF1\\u1CF5\\u1CF6\\u1D00-\\u1DBF\\u1E00-\\u1F15\\u1F18-\\u1F1D\\u1F20-\\u1F45\\u1F48-\\u1F4D\\u1F50-\\u1F57\\u1F59\\u1F5B\\u1F5D\\u1F5F-\\u1F7D\\u1F80-\\u1FB4\\u1FB6-\\u1FBC\\u1FBE\\u1FC2-\\u1FC4\\u1FC6-\\u1FCC\\u1FD0-\\u1FD3\\u1FD6-\\u1FDB\\u1FE0-\\u1FEC\\u1FF2-\\u1FF4\\u1FF6-\\u1FFC\\u2071\\u207F\\u2090-\\u209C\\u2102\\u2107\\u210A-\\u2113\\u2115\\u2119-\\u211D\\u2124\\u2126\\u2128\\u212A-\\u212D\\u212F-\\u2139\\u213C-\\u213F\\u2145-\\u2149\\u214E\\u2183\\u2184\\u2C00-\\u2C2E\\u2C30-\\u2C5E\\u2C60-\\u2CE4\\u2CEB-\\u2CEE\\u2CF2\\u2CF3\\u2D00-\\u2D25\\u2D27\\u2D2D\\u2D30-\\u2D67\\u2D6F\\u2D80-\\u2D96\\u2DA0-\\u2DA6\\u2DA8-\\u2DAE\\u2DB0-\\u2DB6\\u2DB8-\\u2DBE\\u2DC0-\\u2DC6\\u2DC8-\\u2DCE\\u2DD0-\\u2DD6\\u2DD8-\\u2DDE\\u2E2F\\u3005\\u3006\\u3031-\\u3035\\u303B\\u303C\\u3041-\\u3096\\u309D-\\u309F\\u30A1-\\u30FA\\u30FC-\\u30FF\\u3105-\\u312D\\u3131-\\u318E\\u31A0-\\u31BA\\u31F0-\\u31FF\\u3400-\\u4DB5\\u4E00-\\u9FCC\\uA000-\\uA48C\\uA4D0-\\uA4FD\\uA500-\\uA60C\\uA610-\\uA61F\\uA62A\\uA62B\\uA640-\\uA66E\\uA67F-\\uA69D\\uA6A0-\\uA6E5\\uA717-\\uA71F\\uA722-\\uA788\\uA78B-\\uA78E\\uA790-\\uA7AD\\uA7B0\\uA7B1\\uA7F7-\\uA801\\uA803-\\uA805\\uA807-\\uA80A\\uA80C-\\uA822\\uA840-\\uA873\\uA882-\\uA8B3\\uA8F2-\\uA8F7\\uA8FB\\uA90A-\\uA925\\uA930-\\uA946\\uA960-\\uA97C\\uA984-\\uA9B2\\uA9CF\\uA9E0-\\uA9E4\\uA9E6-\\uA9EF\\uA9FA-\\uA9FE\\uAA00-\\uAA28\\uAA40-\\uAA42\\uAA44-\\uAA4B\\uAA60-\\uAA76\\uAA7A\\uAA7E-\\uAAAF\\uAAB1\\uAAB5\\uAAB6\\uAAB9-\\uAABD\\uAAC0\\uAAC2\\uAADB-\\uAADD\\uAAE0-\\uAAEA\\uAAF2-\\uAAF4\\uAB01-\\uAB06\\uAB09-\\uAB0E\\uAB11-\\uAB16\\uAB20-\\uAB26\\uAB28-\\uAB2E\\uAB30-\\uAB5A\\uAB5C-\\uAB5F\\uAB64\\uAB65\\uABC0-\\uABE2\\uAC00-\\uD7A3\\uD7B0-\\uD7C6\\uD7CB-\\uD7FB\\uF900-\\uFA6D\\uFA70-\\uFAD9\\uFB00-\\uFB06\\uFB13-\\uFB17\\uFB1D\\uFB1F-\\uFB28\\uFB2A-\\uFB36\\uFB38-\\uFB3C\\uFB3E\\uFB40\\uFB41\\uFB43\\uFB44\\uFB46-\\uFBB1\\uFBD3-\\uFD3D\\uFD50-\\uFD8F\\uFD92-\\uFDC7\\uFDF0-\\uFDFB\\uFE70-\\uFE74\\uFE76-\\uFEFC\\uFF21-\\uFF3A\\uFF41-\\uFF5A\\uFF66-\\uFFBE\\uFFC2-\\uFFC7\\uFFCA-\\uFFCF\\uFFD2-\\uFFD7\\uFFDA-\\uFFDC";
var w_pattern = "[_0-9a-zA-Z" + pL + "]"; // Matches one or more letters, ASCII digits and underscores (almost \w in .NET)
var your_pattern = RegExp(w_pattern + "[" + w_pattern + "–-]*" + w_pattern); // = \w[\w\-\–]*\w (no Unicode digits, only ASCII ones 0-9)
```

It looks like you want to use `[^\x00-\x7F]` instead. **Do that only in case you do not care if you match a letter or any other Unicode symbol.**

Comment: Thank you Wiktorze, for the answer, but in case of more complex expressions it's problematic. At first - size. The second thing is if I simply replace \w with this tricky part it doesn't work so well anymore.

Comment: This `\w[\w\-\–]*\w` regex is very poorly written. I believe you wanted `\w+(?:[-–]\w+)*`. What are the requirements? And you can always define the regex with the constructor notation, and use it as a regex buliding block to make it manageable. Again, you may use XRegExp. Please clarify what your final regex or how you intend to use it in Angular.

Comment: I added the JS code to show how your pattern can be written with a RegExp constructor. Note I assume you only want to match ASCII digits. If not, please let know.