# How can I match first letter of every word except words in braces with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to do this forever. I can match first letter of every word, but I can't exclude words which are in braces.

For example:

> I can't (do) this, please (help) me.

So this should match - `I`, `c`, `t`, `p`, `m` - only.

Using `\b\w` only matches first letters of the word, it doesn't exclude words in braces. I've tried also negative lookahead, but seems like I can't do it properly:

```
(?!\(()\))\b\w
```

Also I've got the problem with the unicodes. Using `(?:^| )[a-z]{1}` or `\b\w` only matches latin letters and I sometimes will have different unicodes, for example:

> I am (someone) ვიღაც.

And in this situation regex will only match `I`, `a` and `s`, not `ვ`. Thanks

Comment: Try: `"I can't (do) this, please (help) me".match(/(?:^| )[a-z]{1}/gi)`. Not tested though.

Comment: Please note: To avoid down votes show what you've tried so far

Comment: Thanks! It works, but it also matches spaces before letters. "I", " c", " t", " p" ...

Comment: OK, when you want to match non-latin chars too, then you shouldn't use `RegExp`, because even in ES6 there's no support for unicode char classes.

Comment: Alright, thanks, didn't know that. So I should match one char after space.

Answer (score 1):

this one catch only the first letter of words :

> (?<=[^(])\b\w

this is a positive lookbehind : ( from https://regex101.com/)

Ensures that the given pattern will match, ending at the current position in the expression. Does not consume any characters.

> /(?<=foo)bar/

foobar match
 foobaz don't match

For non-latin caracters i can't help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, positive lookbehind isn't supported in javascript. I've forgot to mention about the js in OP, but this question is tagged with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Different things to be considered.

1. First you need to define your letters that can also be non-latin ones. [See this answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/150078/5527985). So to match a letter let's use `[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]`
2. As you want to do this in Javascript, regex is limited. A word boundary `\b` cannot be used as it does not match the specified letter range. Lookbehind is not available. We need to use a [negated class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) of the specified letter. Something like `(?:^|[^'\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w-])` as a "word boundary". Here I also added `'` to avoid matches in such as `can't`
3. Use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for checking to be outside of parenthesis: `(?![^(]*\))`

All together the pattern would look like

```
(?:^|[^'\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w])([\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w])(?![^(]*\))
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/22hpLqky/) and [demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mJ1kY7/2)

Comment: Great `RegExp` stunt! Not very reliable though. Probably too many exceptions: `"code-breaking text".match(/(?:^|[^'a-z\w])([a-z\w])(?![^(]*\))/gi)`

Comment: @LUH3417 thank you for comment (: you mean because of the `-`? [It can be modified to needs](https://regex101.com/r/eJ5nE8/2).