# Language agnostic slug in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried slugify and slug packages but strings like `കവാടം പൊളിക്കണം: "ലോ അക്കാദമിക്കു" നോട്ടിസ്` return a blank string instead of `കവാടം-പൊളിക്കണം-ലോ-അക്കാദമിക്കു-നോട്ടിസ്`. Words should be preserved, special characters should be stripped.

Is there a way to generate slugs that preserves arbitrary non-English words?

---

[Regular expression to match non-English characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters) seems the best resource for matching international words.

Comment: With [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) you should be able to do that fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

This following regEx match-replace worked fine for spaces only.

```js
var s    = 'കവാടം പൊളിക്കണം: "ലോ അക്കാദമിക്കു" നോട്ടിസ്';
var res  = s.replace(/ /g,"-");
console.log( res );
```

---

For all special characters you can use following.

```js
var s    = 'കവാടം പൊളിക്കണം: "ലോ അക്കാദമിക്കു" നോട്ടിസ്';

// Keep symbols you want to replace with hyphen.
var res  = s.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{} ]/g,"-");
console.log( res );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple enough to do with `String.prototype.replace()` or with regular expressions. Did you try:

```
'കവാടം പൊളിക്കണം'.replace(' ', '-')
```

It returns `"കവാടം-പൊളിക്കണം"`.